# Fetching records with slug instead of ID

Tags: database, performance, url, select, slug

I'm currently trying to find the best way (in term of usability and performance) when dealing with a situation like fetching records tagged with a specific tag, or category, or something like that.

A good way (the way I wanted to do), would be to fetch records with the tag/category slug, so the URL would look like :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic
```

fetching records by slug, which looks better than :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tag/789/language-agnostic
```

fetching by ID and adding the slug behind so it's more search-engine friendly. This one is better performance-wise, because fetching data by an integer ID would be faster than a string. (cmiiw)

Now, with a db schema like :

```
posts    post_to_tags    tags
-----    ------------    ----
id       id              id
title    post_id         name
content  tag_id          slug
...                      ...
```

am I doing it right ? Is there pitfall or best-practices that I need to know to avoid performance problems ? (eg. tags should not exceed 10,000 records, or tag slug should not exceed n characters, or something else)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the first URL style and your current db design, you can do this:

```
select ...
from   posts p
join   posts_to_tags pt on pt.post_id = p.post_id
join   tags t on t.id = pt.tag_id
where  t.slug = [url slug value];
```

As long as tags.slug is indexed, this should be very efficient, *hardly* any different from

```
select ...
from   posts p
join   posts_to_tags pt on pt.post_id = p.post_id
where  pt.tag_id = [url tag ID];
```

Comment: in the case where there's 10,000 but indexed varchar(30) tags vs the integer one, how much, approximately, is the difference we are talking about ?

Comment: Well, we're just talking about one indexed read of the tags table using the given slug value to get the tag_id, so it's peanuts.  On Oracle I just experimented 10,000 selects either way and got timings of 1.078 and 1.312 seconds - i.e. 0.0234 milliseconds per query!

Comment: I mean, i.e. a *difference of* 0.0234 milliseconds per query.

Comment: wow, I really appreciate that. Thanks a lot Tony ! Nice age you have there btw.

Comment: Note too Andy, that 2 articles *may* (depending on your application) have the same slug... in this case an ID followed by the slug is better.

Comment: yup, that's the extra hassle. I handle the checking and renaming stuff from the CMS, whenever new entry is inserted, following Wordpress' example, eg. some-slug-url into some-slug-url-2. Not so beautiful IMO, that's why ppl should avoid using this method when .. damn 300 characters limit..

Comment: .. that's why people should avoid using this method when the site is heavily-packed with entries, especially when the entries are user-generated. Thanks Alex for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is better, but can the slugs possibly be changed? In that case you'd need to have a redirect table (e.g. "some-article-about-dogs" is now "article-about-dogs-and-cats").