# PHP function to make slug (URL string)

Tags: php, internationalization, slug

I want to have a function to create slugs from Unicode strings, e.g. `gen_slug('Andrés Cortez')` should return `andres-cortez`. How should I do that?

Comment: Returns 'andres' for me. You sure?

Comment: I copied your code here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and it outputs `andres`. Are you sure your input is exactly "andrés"?

Comment: in plain php it works. sorry, i forgot to mention that the function is being executed from an ajax function server side. Maybe the problem is happening because of a charset feature?

Comment: here is a good working solution for cyrilic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461406/cyrillic-transliteration-in-php

Comment: Do not forget to add setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB'); if you receive to much sings '?' after function use. 'en_GB' your expected locale.

Comment: Also see [How Stack Overflow generates its SEO-friendly URLs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-does-stack-overflow-generate-its-seo-friendly-urls).

Comment: Instead of building your own solution, you can use an existing library like https://github.com/cocur/slugify or https://github.com/ausi/slug-generator

Comment: My answer [down below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66904781/9583480) is getting more and more popular. It was used in my last company, and was now adopted in my new company. If you find any issues with it that we haven't, please let me know in the comments. Kindest regards.

Comment: Please change the accepted answer to hdogan one that is from far the best (Maerlyn's answer is totally wrong and people continues to upvote it).

Answer (score 564, accepted):

Instead of a lengthy replace, try this one:

```
public static function slugify($text, string $divider = '-')
{
  // replace non letter or digits by divider
  $text = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d]+~u', $divider, $text);

  // transliterate
  $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);

  // remove unwanted characters
  $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);

  // trim
  $text = trim($text, $divider);

  // remove duplicate divider
  $text = preg_replace('~-+~', $divider, $text);

  // lowercase
  $text = strtolower($text);

  if (empty($text)) {
    return 'n-a';
  }

  return $text;
}
```

This was based off the one in Symfony's Jobeet tutorial.

Comment: you sure? the first preg_replace wipes all normal text too :s

Comment: No, the first preg_replace wipes everything that's not a character or a digit. Note the `^` just after the opening bracket - it reverses the match.

Comment: `iconv` will not convert correctly if `$text` contains characters that don't have ascii equivalent. For example `iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', "EFI收购Cretaprint")` will return `"EFI"` and leak a warning.

Comment: @Maerlyn and andufo, I think there is an extra "\" though in the first regex, correct? Should be '~[^\pL\d]+~u' ?

Comment: No, it's there because you need to escape the backslash.

Comment: Best slug function I've seen... I'd maybe make sure the slug is a certain length however.

Comment: Confirming that it's not working with Cyrillic and probably other non ASCII encodings. In my case a problem was with `í` letter.

Comment: `$text = trim($text, '-');` should be at the end, otherwise `Foo 收` becomes `foo-`. Also, `Foo 收 Bar` becomes `foo--bar` (the repeated `-` seems redundant).

Comment: No no no no this does not work. The first expression DOES replace all non letter characters. Should not be accepted.

Comment: Just want to add that I also used `utf8_encode($text)` before the `iconv` line so that it would not produce an empty string.

Comment: I tried it with WordPress used WP All Import plugin but I had problem with latin characters.

Comment: mb_ereg_replace will help instead of preg_replace

Comment: @mindsupport ereg was deprecated a long time ago, don't use it.

Comment: @Maerlyn Can we also use same function for validate the slug ? like `if (slugify($text) !== 'n-a'){echo 'Correct Slug';}`

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)

Comment: @KasparL.Palgi remove that if you're not putting it in a class. `static` as well.

Comment: @Maerlyn: `mb_ereg` isn't deprecated at all.

Comment: Why am i getting `Warning: iconv(): Wrong encoding, conversion from 'utf-8' to 'us-ascii\/\/TRANSLIT' is not allowed`

Comment: @NgatiaFrankline you seem to be running into a docker/alpine issue, google seems to have a few solutions, like installing mbstring and iconv in this order.

Comment: works nicely but failing when I pass string with a very specific character like '’' in L’OR . By failing I mean returns 'n-a'

Comment: This doesn't seem to work `Lán` is converted into `la-n` instead of `lan`. It adds extra dividers after each character that needs the transformation.

Answer (score 68):

#### Update

Since this answer is getting some attention, I'm adding some explanation.

The solution provided will essentially replace everything except A-Z, a-z, 0-9, & - (hyphen) with - (hyphen). So, it won't work properly with other unicode characters (which are valid characters for a URL slug/string). A common scenario is when the input string contains non-English characters.

Only use this solution if you're confident that the input string won't have unicode characters which you might want to be a part of output/slug.

Eg. "नारी शक्ति" will become "----------" (all hyphens) instead of "नारी-शक्ति" (valid URL slug).

#### Answer

```
$slug = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $string)));
```

Comment: Actually it does. This thread is sooooo strange... the accepted answer does not work, all the other kinda of do...

Comment: It provides an answer to the question asked in the title which is what led me here and to this answer, which was perfect for my needs.

Comment: Just adding to this, not 100% tested, I found if you initially replaced all spaces with a dash, then used this function to remove any other characters to replace them with an empty value eg. ''

Comment: `strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', "Étienne")))` returns `"-tienne"` instead of `"etienne"`, so it does not works with accented characters.

Comment: slugs generated this way are in no way SEO-friendly or user-friendly. Also, they generate a lot of collisions in many languages, many more than proper transliteration would cause.

Comment: Useful modification: `function slugify($t) { return preg_replace('/-{2,}/', '-', strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '', str_replace(' ', '-', $t))))); }` this one replaces 1) spaces by `-`  2) non alphanumeric by empty  3) multiple `----` by a single one.

Comment: In this answer, `trim()` is a 100% useless call.  There are no possible whitespace characters in the string because the initial `preg_replace()` call destroys them all.  Many readers have been mislead by this suboptimal answer.

Answer (score 58):

If you have [intl](http://php.net/intl) extension installed, you can use [Transliterator::transliterate](http://php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php) function to create a slug easily.

```
$string = 'Namnet på bildtävlingen';

$rules = <<<'RULES'
    :: Any-Latin;
    :: NFD;
    :: [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove;
    :: NFC;
    :: [^-[:^Punctuation:]] Remove;
    :: Lower();
    [:^L:] { [-] > ;
    [-] } [:^L:] > ;
    [-[:Separator:]]+ > '-';
RULES;

$slug = \Transliterator::createFromRules($rules)
    ->transliterate( $string );

echo $slug; // namnet-pa-bildtavlingen
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/ZTuZv)

Note that this solution works whatever the alphabet and is highly flexible.

Comment: For those arriving at this post years later the intl extension is bundled with PHP since 5.3.0. http://php.net/manual/en/intl.requirements.php

Comment: this however removes dash (-), e.g. $string = "My-string hello" returns "mystring-hello"

Comment: To learn about available rules, explore this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17015063/6850820

Comment: The only good answer for this question.

Comment: @undefinedman: this can easily be solved replacing`[:Punctuation:]` with `[^-[:^Punctuation:]]`. A more waterproof solution: https://3v4l.org/FAJAW

Comment: Great solution, thank you! But it transliterates German umlauts to the underlying vowel and not to the form followed by an 'e'. This is important, because e. g. "schon" and "schön" have completely different meanings, so "schön" has to become "schoen". This can easily be solved by adding `de-ASCII` to the rules.

Answer (score 29):

Note: I have taken this from wordpress and it works!!

Use it like this:

```
echo sanitize('testing this link');
```

Code

```
//taken from wordpress
function utf8_uri_encode( $utf8_string, $length = 0 ) {
    $unicode = '';
    $values = array();
    $num_octets = 1;
    $unicode_length = 0;

    $string_length = strlen( $utf8_string );
    for ($i = 0; $i < $string_length; $i++ ) {

        $value = ord( $utf8_string[ $i ] );

        if ( $value < 128 ) {
            if ( $length && ( $unicode_length >= $length ) )
                break;
            $unicode .= chr($value);
            $unicode_length++;
        } else {
            if ( count( $values ) == 0 ) $num_octets = ( $value < 224 ) ? 2 : 3;

            $values[] = $value;

            if ( $length && ( $unicode_length + ($num_octets * 3) ) > $length )
                break;
            if ( count( $values ) == $num_octets ) {
                if ($num_octets == 3) {
                    $unicode .= '%' . dechex($values[0]) . '%' . dechex($values[1]) . '%' . dechex($values[2]);
                    $unicode_length += 9;
                } else {
                    $unicode .= '%' . dechex($values[0]) . '%' . dechex($values[1]);
                    $unicode_length += 6;
                }

                $values = array();
                $num_octets = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return $unicode;
}

//taken from wordpress
function seems_utf8($str) {
    $length = strlen($str);
    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $c = ord($str[$i]);
        if ($c < 0x80) $n = 0; # 0bbbbbbb
        elseif (($c & 0xE0) == 0xC0) $n=1; # 110bbbbb
        elseif (($c & 0xF0) == 0xE0) $n=2; # 1110bbbb
        elseif (($c & 0xF8) == 0xF0) $n=3; # 11110bbb
        elseif (($c & 0xFC) == 0xF8) $n=4; # 111110bb
        elseif (($c & 0xFE) == 0xFC) $n=5; # 1111110b
        else return false; # Does not match any model
        for ($j=0; $j<$n; $j++) { # n bytes matching 10bbbbbb follow ?
            if ((++$i == $length) || ((ord($str[$i]) & 0xC0) != 0x80))
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//function sanitize_title_with_dashes taken from wordpress
function sanitize($title) {
    $title = strip_tags($title);
    // Preserve escaped octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);
    // Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
    $title = str_replace('%', '', $title);
    // Restore octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title);

    if (seems_utf8($title)) {
        if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
            $title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
        }
        $title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 200);
    }

    $title = strtolower($title);
    $title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
    $title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
    $title = trim($title, '-');

    return $title;
}
```

Comment: In WordPress 3.9.1 (which I'm using) I have to call `sanitize_title_with_dashes($string, null, 'save')` (note the extra parameters), otherwise you get some messy character codes like `telstra%e2%80%99s-%e2%80%98all-roles-flex%e2%80%99`.  Not very pretty. :-(

Comment: [See the related answer on this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955251/php-function-to-make-slug-url-string/26286437#26286437) from @czerasz. Links to latest: [formatting.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/formatting.php) also [functions.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/functions.php)

Comment: `sanitize` is a strange, forgettable function name to generate a slug.

Answer (score 15):

It is always a good idea to use existing solutions that are being supported by a lot of high-level developers. The most popular one is https://github.com/cocur/slugify. First of all, it supports more than one language, and it is being updated.

If you do not want to use the whole package, you can copy the part that you need.

Comment: its overkill... we just need a simple, lowercase, no spaces / weird characters function.

Answer (score 12):

Here is an other one, for example "    Title   with strange characters ééé A    X    Z" becomes "title-with-strange-characters-eee-a-x-z".

```
/**
 * Function used to create a slug associated to an "ugly" string.
 *
 * @param string $string the string to transform.
 *
 * @return string the resulting slug.
 */
public static function createSlug($string) {

    $table = array(
            'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Đ'=>'Dj', 'đ'=>'dj', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'Č'=>'C', 'č'=>'c', 'Ć'=>'C', 'ć'=>'c',
            'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
            'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O',
            'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss',
            'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c', 'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e',
            'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o',
            'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b',
            'ÿ'=>'y', 'Ŕ'=>'R', 'ŕ'=>'r', '/' => '-', ' ' => '-'
    );

    // -- Remove duplicated spaces
    $stripped = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $string);

    // -- Returns the slug
    return strtolower(strtr($string, $table));


}
```

Comment: Renamed `$string` and `$stripped` to `$text` and added `$text = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);` before return. Now it works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

```
public static function slugify ($text) {

    $replace = [
        '&lt;' => '', '&gt;' => '', '&#039;' => '', '&amp;' => '',
        '&quot;' => '', 'À' => 'A', 'Á' => 'A', 'Â' => 'A', 'Ã' => 'A', 'Ä'=> 'Ae',
        '&Auml;' => 'A', 'Å' => 'A', 'Ā' => 'A', 'Ą' => 'A', 'Ă' => 'A', 'Æ' => 'Ae',
        'Ç' => 'C', 'Ć' => 'C', 'Č' => 'C', 'Ĉ' => 'C', 'Ċ' => 'C', 'Ď' => 'D', 'Đ' => 'D',
        'Ð' => 'D', 'È' => 'E', 'É' => 'E', 'Ê' => 'E', 'Ë' => 'E', 'Ē' => 'E',
        'Ę' => 'E', 'Ě' => 'E', 'Ĕ' => 'E', 'Ė' => 'E', 'Ĝ' => 'G', 'Ğ' => 'G',
        'Ġ' => 'G', 'Ģ' => 'G', 'Ĥ' => 'H', 'Ħ' => 'H', 'Ì' => 'I', 'Í' => 'I',
        'Î' => 'I', 'Ï' => 'I', 'Ī' => 'I', 'Ĩ' => 'I', 'Ĭ' => 'I', 'Į' => 'I',
        'İ' => 'I', 'Ĳ' => 'IJ', 'Ĵ' => 'J', 'Ķ' => 'K', 'Ł' => 'K', 'Ľ' => 'K',
        'Ĺ' => 'K', 'Ļ' => 'K', 'Ŀ' => 'K', 'Ñ' => 'N', 'Ń' => 'N', 'Ň' => 'N',
        'Ņ' => 'N', 'Ŋ' => 'N', 'Ò' => 'O', 'Ó' => 'O', 'Ô' => 'O', 'Õ' => 'O',
        'Ö' => 'Oe', '&Ouml;' => 'Oe', 'Ø' => 'O', 'Ō' => 'O', 'Ő' => 'O', 'Ŏ' => 'O',
        'Œ' => 'OE', 'Ŕ' => 'R', 'Ř' => 'R', 'Ŗ' => 'R', 'Ś' => 'S', 'Š' => 'S',
        'Ş' => 'S', 'Ŝ' => 'S', 'Ș' => 'S', 'Ť' => 'T', 'Ţ' => 'T', 'Ŧ' => 'T',
        'Ț' => 'T', 'Ù' => 'U', 'Ú' => 'U', 'Û' => 'U', 'Ü' => 'Ue', 'Ū' => 'U',
        '&Uuml;' => 'Ue', 'Ů' => 'U', 'Ű' => 'U', 'Ŭ' => 'U', 'Ũ' => 'U', 'Ų' => 'U',
        'Ŵ' => 'W', 'Ý' => 'Y', 'Ŷ' => 'Y', 'Ÿ' => 'Y', 'Ź' => 'Z', 'Ž' => 'Z',
        'Ż' => 'Z', 'Þ' => 'T', 'à' => 'a', 'á' => 'a', 'â' => 'a', 'ã' => 'a',
        'ä' => 'ae', '&auml;' => 'ae', 'å' => 'a', 'ā' => 'a', 'ą' => 'a', 'ă' => 'a',
        'æ' => 'ae', 'ç' => 'c', 'ć' => 'c', 'č' => 'c', 'ĉ' => 'c', 'ċ' => 'c',
        'ď' => 'd', 'đ' => 'd', 'ð' => 'd', 'è' => 'e', 'é' => 'e', 'ê' => 'e',
        'ë' => 'e', 'ē' => 'e', 'ę' => 'e', 'ě' => 'e', 'ĕ' => 'e', 'ė' => 'e',
        'ƒ' => 'f', 'ĝ' => 'g', 'ğ' => 'g', 'ġ' => 'g', 'ģ' => 'g', 'ĥ' => 'h',
        'ħ' => 'h', 'ì' => 'i', 'í' => 'i', 'î' => 'i', 'ï' => 'i', 'ī' => 'i',
        'ĩ' => 'i', 'ĭ' => 'i', 'į' => 'i', 'ı' => 'i', 'ĳ' => 'ij', 'ĵ' => 'j',
        'ķ' => 'k', 'ĸ' => 'k', 'ł' => 'l', 'ľ' => 'l', 'ĺ' => 'l', 'ļ' => 'l',
        'ŀ' => 'l', 'ñ' => 'n', 'ń' => 'n', 'ň' => 'n', 'ņ' => 'n', 'ŉ' => 'n',
        'ŋ' => 'n', 'ò' => 'o', 'ó' => 'o', 'ô' => 'o', 'õ' => 'o', 'ö' => 'oe',
        '&ouml;' => 'oe', 'ø' => 'o', 'ō' => 'o', 'ő' => 'o', 'ŏ' => 'o', 'œ' => 'oe',
        'ŕ' => 'r', 'ř' => 'r', 'ŗ' => 'r', 'š' => 's', 'ù' => 'u', 'ú' => 'u',
        'û' => 'u', 'ü' => 'ue', 'ū' => 'u', '&uuml;' => 'ue', 'ů' => 'u', 'ű' => 'u',
        'ŭ' => 'u', 'ũ' => 'u', 'ų' => 'u', 'ŵ' => 'w', 'ý' => 'y', 'ÿ' => 'y',
        'ŷ' => 'y', 'ž' => 'z', 'ż' => 'z', 'ź' => 'z', 'þ' => 't', 'ß' => 'ss',
        'ſ' => 'ss', 'ый' => 'iy', 'А' => 'A', 'Б' => 'B', 'В' => 'V', 'Г' => 'G',
        'Д' => 'D', 'Е' => 'E', 'Ё' => 'YO', 'Ж' => 'ZH', 'З' => 'Z', 'И' => 'I',
        'Й' => 'Y', 'К' => 'K', 'Л' => 'L', 'М' => 'M', 'Н' => 'N', 'О' => 'O',
        'П' => 'P', 'Р' => 'R', 'С' => 'S', 'Т' => 'T', 'У' => 'U', 'Ф' => 'F',
        'Х' => 'H', 'Ц' => 'C', 'Ч' => 'CH', 'Ш' => 'SH', 'Щ' => 'SCH', 'Ъ' => '',
        'Ы' => 'Y', 'Ь' => '', 'Э' => 'E', 'Ю' => 'YU', 'Я' => 'YA', 'а' => 'a',
        'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', 'г' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e', 'ё' => 'yo',
        'ж' => 'zh', 'з' => 'z', 'и' => 'i', 'й' => 'y', 'к' => 'k', 'л' => 'l',
        'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n', 'о' => 'o', 'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r', 'с' => 's',
        'т' => 't', 'у' => 'u', 'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'c', 'ч' => 'ch',
        'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'sch', 'ъ' => '', 'ы' => 'y', 'ь' => '', 'э' => 'e',
        'ю' => 'yu', 'я' => 'ya'
    ];

    // make a human readable string
    $text = strtr($text, $replace);

    // replace non letter or digits by -
    $text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d.]+~u', '-', $text);

    // trim
    $text = trim($text, '-');

    // remove unwanted characters
    $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w.]+~', '', $text);

    $text = strtolower($text);

    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nady, welcome to SO. Code-only answers are discouraged here as they don't teach others _how_ to code. Could you edit your post to explain what your code sample does and how it answers the question? Thanks.

Comment: The code is self explanatory through comments. I have no extra information to expose here. So you can know what i am trying to do just by reading doc blocks

Answer (score 9):

There are already many answers here, so I almost don't want to add another one, but none of the functions did everything I needed.

The best basis for me was function number 3 where their speed was compared. I added/fixed some replacements so

1. `'` is just deleted,
2. `.` is replaced by `-`,
3. `α` is replaced by `a`,
4. `ẞ` is replaced by `b`,
5. `Ł` (and similar) is replaced by `L` instead of `K`, and
6. `€` and `$` signs are replaced with `eur` and `usd` respectively (add more on necessity).

Optionally you can add `'&' => '-and-'`, but SEO advises against usage of conjunctions ([#8](https://moz.com/blog/15-seo-best-practices-for-structuring-urls)), so I left it out for my use-case. *(this function doesn't strip existing `and`s and `or`s from the string though)*

I also added a line of code to fix double dash in this weird string I came up with, as well as an optional parameter to limit slug's length.

#### Code

```php
<?php
function slugify($text, $length = null)
{
    $replacements = [
        '<' => '', '>' => '', '-' => ' ', '&' => '', '"' => '', 'À' => 'A', 'Á' => 'A', 'Â' => 'A', 'Ã' => 'A', 'Ä' => 'Ae', 'Ä' => 'A', 'Å' => 'A', 'Ā' => 'A', 'Ą' => 'A', 'Ă' => 'A', 'Æ' => 'Ae', 'Ç' => 'C', "'" => '', 'Ć' => 'C', 'Č' => 'C', 'Ĉ' => 'C', 'Ċ' => 'C', 'Ď' => 'D', 'Đ' => 'D', 'Ð' => 'D', 'È' => 'E', 'É' => 'E', 'Ê' => 'E', 'Ë' => 'E', 'Ē' => 'E', 'Ę' => 'E', 'Ě' => 'E', 'Ĕ' => 'E', 'Ė' => 'E', 'Ĝ' => 'G', 'Ğ' => 'G', 'Ġ' => 'G', 'Ģ' => 'G', 'Ĥ' => 'H', 'Ħ' => 'H', 'Ì' => 'I', 'Í' => 'I', 'Î' => 'I', 'Ï' => 'I', 'Ī' => 'I', 'Ĩ' => 'I', 'Ĭ' => 'I', 'Į' => 'I', 'İ' => 'I', 'Ĳ' => 'IJ', 'Ĵ' => 'J', 'Ķ' => 'K', 'Ł' => 'L', 'Ľ' => 'L', 'Ĺ' => 'L', 'Ļ' => 'L', 'Ŀ' => 'L', 'Ñ' => 'N', 'Ń' => 'N', 'Ň' => 'N', 'Ņ' => 'N', 'Ŋ' => 'N', 'Ò' => 'O', 'Ó' => 'O', 'Ô' => 'O', 'Õ' => 'O', 'Ö' => 'Oe', 'Ö' => 'Oe', 'Ø' => 'O', 'Ō' => 'O', 'Ő' => 'O', 'Ŏ' => 'O', 'Œ' => 'OE', 'Ŕ' => 'R', 'Ř' => 'R', 'Ŗ' => 'R', 'Ś' => 'S', 'Š' => 'S', 'Ş' => 'S', 'Ŝ' => 'S', 'Ș' => 'S', 'Ť' => 'T', 'Ţ' => 'T', 'Ŧ' => 'T', 'Ț' => 'T', 'Ù' => 'U', 'Ú' => 'U', 'Û' => 'U', 'Ü' => 'Ue', 'Ū' => 'U', 'Ü' => 'Ue', 'Ů' => 'U', 'Ű' => 'U', 'Ŭ' => 'U', 'Ũ' => 'U', 'Ų' => 'U', 'Ŵ' => 'W', 'Ý' => 'Y', 'Ŷ' => 'Y', 'Ÿ' => 'Y', 'Ź' => 'Z', 'Ž' => 'Z', 'Ż' => 'Z', 'Þ' => 'T', 'à' => 'a', 'á' => 'a', 'â' => 'a', 'ã' => 'a', 'ä' => 'ae', 'ä' => 'ae', 'å' => 'a', 'ā' => 'a', 'ą' => 'a', 'ă' => 'a', 'æ' => 'ae', 'ç' => 'c', 'ć' => 'c', 'č' => 'c', 'ĉ' => 'c', 'ċ' => 'c', 'ď' => 'd', 'đ' => 'd', 'ð' => 'd', 'è' => 'e', 'é' => 'e', 'ê' => 'e', 'ë' => 'e', 'ē' => 'e', 'ę' => 'e', 'ě' => 'e', 'ĕ' => 'e', 'ė' => 'e', 'ƒ' => 'f', 'ĝ' => 'g', 'ğ' => 'g', 'ġ' => 'g', 'ģ' => 'g', 'ĥ' => 'h', 'ħ' => 'h', 'ì' => 'i', 'í' => 'i', 'î' => 'i', 'ï' => 'i', 'ī' => 'i', 'ĩ' => 'i', 'ĭ' => 'i', 'į' => 'i', 'ı' => 'i', 'ĳ' => 'ij', 'ĵ' => 'j', 'ķ' => 'k', 'ĸ' => 'k', 'ł' => 'l', 'ľ' => 'l', 'ĺ' => 'l', 'ļ' => 'l', 'ŀ' => 'l', 'ñ' => 'n', 'ń' => 'n', 'ň' => 'n', 'ņ' => 'n', 'ŉ' => 'n', 'ŋ' => 'n', 'ò' => 'o', 'ó' => 'o', 'ô' => 'o', 'õ' => 'o', 'ö' => 'oe', 'ö' => 'oe', 'ø' => 'o', 'ō' => 'o', 'ő' => 'o', 'ŏ' => 'o', 'œ' => 'oe', 'ŕ' => 'r', 'ř' => 'r', 'ŗ' => 'r', 'š' => 's', 'ś' => 's', 'ù' => 'u', 'ú' => 'u', 'û' => 'u', 'ü' => 'ue', 'ū' => 'u', 'ü' => 'ue', 'ů' => 'u', 'ű' => 'u', 'ŭ' => 'u', 'ũ' => 'u', 'ų' => 'u', 'ŵ' => 'w', 'ý' => 'y', 'ÿ' => 'y', 'ŷ' => 'y', 'ž' => 'z', 'ż' => 'z', 'ź' => 'z', 'þ' => 't', 'α' => 'a', 'ß' => 'ss', 'ẞ' => 'b', 'ſ' => 'ss', 'ый' => 'iy', 'А' => 'A', 'Б' => 'B', 'В' => 'V', 'Г' => 'G', 'Д' => 'D', 'Е' => 'E', 'Ё' => 'YO', 'Ж' => 'ZH', 'З' => 'Z', 'И' => 'I', 'Й' => 'Y', 'К' => 'K', 'Л' => 'L', 'М' => 'M', 'Н' => 'N', 'О' => 'O', 'П' => 'P', 'Р' => 'R', 'С' => 'S', 'Т' => 'T', 'У' => 'U', 'Ф' => 'F', 'Х' => 'H', 'Ц' => 'C', 'Ч' => 'CH', 'Ш' => 'SH', 'Щ' => 'SCH', 'Ъ' => '', 'Ы' => 'Y', 'Ь' => '', 'Э' => 'E', 'Ю' => 'YU', 'Я' => 'YA', 'а' => 'a', 'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', 'г' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e', 'ё' => 'yo', 'ж' => 'zh', 'з' => 'z', 'и' => 'i', 'й' => 'y', 'к' => 'k', 'л' => 'l', 'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n', 'о' => 'o', 'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r', 'с' => 's', 'т' => 't', 'у' => 'u', 'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'c', 'ч' => 'ch', 'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'sch', 'ъ' => '', 'ы' => 'y', 'ь' => '', 'э' => 'e', 'ю' => 'yu', 'я' => 'ya', '.' => '-', '€' => '-eur-', '$' => '-usd-'
    ];
    // Replace non-ascii characters
    $text = strtr($text, $replacements);
    // Replace non letter or digits with "-"
    $text = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d.]+~u', '-', $text);
    // Replace unwanted characters with "-"
    $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w.]+~', '-', $text);
    // Trim "-"
    $text = trim($text, '-');
    // Remove duplicate "-"
    $text = preg_replace('~-+~', '-', $text);
    // Convert to lowercase
    $text = strtolower($text);
    // Limit length
    if (isset($length) && $length < strlen($text))
        $text = rtrim(substr($text, 0, $length), '-');

    return $text;
}
$text = "--- You can't misuse me! Or can-ya? ČĆŽŠĐ÷×ß¤_.,:;-!\"#$%&/()=?*~ˇ^˘°˛`˙´˝¨¸¸¨Łł€\|@{}[] ¿ Àñdréß l'affreux ğarçon & nøël en forêt ! Andrés Cortez EFI收购Cretaprint Étienne";
echo "text\n$text\n\nslug\n".slugify($text);
```

#### Output

```html
text
--- You can't misuse me! Or can-ya? ČĆŽŠĐ÷×ß¤_.,:;-!"#$%&/()=?*~ˇ^˘°˛`˙´˝¨¸¸¨Łł€\|@{}[] ¿ Àñdréß l'affreux ğarçon & nøël en forêt ! Andrés Cortez EFI收购Cretaprint Étienne

slug
you-cant-misuse-me-or-can-ya-cczsd-ss-usd-ll-eur-andress-laffreux-garcon-noel-en-foret-andres-cortez-efi-cretaprint-etienne
```

#### Note

It also works for OP's case for converting `'Andrés Cortez'` to `'andres-cortez'` and all other examples I have found in this thread, except this character which is beyond me: .

*I'll be thrilled to know about bugs you found (hopefully accompanied with suggestions).*

Answer (score 8):

An updated version of @Imran Omar Bukhsh code (from the latest Wordpress (4.0) branch):

```
<?php

// Add methods to slugify taken from Wordpress:
// - https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/formatting.php 
// - https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/functions.php

/**
 * Set the mbstring internal encoding to a binary safe encoding when func_overload
 * is enabled.
 *
 * When mbstring.func_overload is in use for multi-byte encodings, the results from
 * strlen() and similar functions respect the utf8 characters, causing binary data
 * to return incorrect lengths.
 *
 * This function overrides the mbstring encoding to a binary-safe encoding, and
 * resets it to the users expected encoding afterwards through the
 * `reset_mbstring_encoding` function.
 *
 * It is safe to recursively call this function, however each
 * `mbstring_binary_safe_encoding()` call must be followed up with an equal number
 * of `reset_mbstring_encoding()` calls.
 *
 * @since 3.7.0
 *
 * @see reset_mbstring_encoding()
 *
 * @param bool $reset Optional. Whether to reset the encoding back to a previously-set encoding.
 *                    Default false.
 */
function mbstring_binary_safe_encoding( $reset = false ) {
  static $encodings = array();
  static $overloaded = null;

  if ( is_null( $overloaded ) )
    $overloaded = function_exists( 'mb_internal_encoding' ) && ( ini_get( 'mbstring.func_overload' ) & 2 );

  if ( false === $overloaded )
    return;

  if ( ! $reset ) {
    $encoding = mb_internal_encoding();
    array_push( $encodings, $encoding );
    mb_internal_encoding( 'ISO-8859-1' );
  }

  if ( $reset && $encodings ) {
    $encoding = array_pop( $encodings );
    mb_internal_encoding( $encoding );
  }
}

/**
 * Reset the mbstring internal encoding to a users previously set encoding.
 *
 * @see mbstring_binary_safe_encoding()
 *
 * @since 3.7.0
 */
function reset_mbstring_encoding() {
  mbstring_binary_safe_encoding( true );
}


/**
 * Checks to see if a string is utf8 encoded.
 *
 * NOTE: This function checks for 5-Byte sequences, UTF8
 *       has Bytes Sequences with a maximum length of 4.
 *
 * @author bmorel at ssi dot fr (modified)
 * @since 1.2.1
 *
 * @param string $str The string to be checked
 * @return bool True if $str fits a UTF-8 model, false otherwise.
 */
function seems_utf8($str) {
  mbstring_binary_safe_encoding();
  $length = strlen($str);
  reset_mbstring_encoding();
  for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $c = ord($str[$i]);
    if ($c < 0x80) $n = 0; # 0bbbbbbb
    elseif (($c & 0xE0) == 0xC0) $n=1; # 110bbbbb
    elseif (($c & 0xF0) == 0xE0) $n=2; # 1110bbbb
    elseif (($c & 0xF8) == 0xF0) $n=3; # 11110bbb
    elseif (($c & 0xFC) == 0xF8) $n=4; # 111110bb
    elseif (($c & 0xFE) == 0xFC) $n=5; # 1111110b
    else return false; # Does not match any model
    for ($j=0; $j<$n; $j++) { # n bytes matching 10bbbbbb follow ?
      if ((++$i == $length) || ((ord($str[$i]) & 0xC0) != 0x80))
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}


/**
 * Encode the Unicode values to be used in the URI.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 *
 * @param string $utf8_string
 * @param int $length Max length of the string
 * @return string String with Unicode encoded for URI.
 */
function utf8_uri_encode( $utf8_string, $length = 0 ) {
  $unicode = '';
  $values = array();
  $num_octets = 1;
  $unicode_length = 0;

  mbstring_binary_safe_encoding();
  $string_length = strlen( $utf8_string );
  reset_mbstring_encoding();

  for ($i = 0; $i < $string_length; $i++ ) {

    $value = ord( $utf8_string[ $i ] );

    if ( $value < 128 ) {
      if ( $length && ( $unicode_length >= $length ) )
        break;
      $unicode .= chr($value);
      $unicode_length++;
    } else {
      if ( count( $values ) == 0 ) $num_octets = ( $value < 224 ) ? 2 : 3;

      $values[] = $value;

      if ( $length && ( $unicode_length + ($num_octets * 3) ) > $length )
        break;
      if ( count( $values ) == $num_octets ) {
        if ($num_octets == 3) {
          $unicode .= '%' . dechex($values[0]) . '%' . dechex($values[1]) . '%' . dechex($values[2]);
          $unicode_length += 9;
        } else {
          $unicode .= '%' . dechex($values[0]) . '%' . dechex($values[1]);
          $unicode_length += 6;
        }

        $values = array();
        $num_octets = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  return $unicode;
}


/**
 * Sanitizes a title, replacing whitespace and a few other characters with dashes.
 *
 * Limits the output to alphanumeric characters, underscore (_) and dash (-).
 * Whitespace becomes a dash.
 *
 * @since 1.2.0
 *
 * @param string $title The title to be sanitized.
 * @param string $raw_title Optional. Not used.
 * @param string $context Optional. The operation for which the string is sanitized.
 * @return string The sanitized title.
 */
function sanitize_title_with_dashes( $title, $raw_title = '', $context = 'display' ) {
  $title = strip_tags($title);
  // Preserve escaped octets.
  $title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);
  // Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
  $title = str_replace('%', '', $title);
  // Restore octets.
  $title = preg_replace('|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title);

  if (seems_utf8($title)) {
    if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
      $title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
    }
    $title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 200);
  }

  $title = strtolower($title);
  $title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
  $title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);

  if ( 'save' == $context ) {
    // Convert nbsp, ndash and mdash to hyphens
    $title = str_replace( array( '%c2%a0', '%e2%80%93', '%e2%80%94' ), '-', $title );

    // Strip these characters entirely
    $title = str_replace( array(
      // iexcl and iquest
      '%c2%a1', '%c2%bf',
      // angle quotes
      '%c2%ab', '%c2%bb', '%e2%80%b9', '%e2%80%ba',
      // curly quotes
      '%e2%80%98', '%e2%80%99', '%e2%80%9c', '%e2%80%9d',
      '%e2%80%9a', '%e2%80%9b', '%e2%80%9e', '%e2%80%9f',
      // copy, reg, deg, hellip and trade
      '%c2%a9', '%c2%ae', '%c2%b0', '%e2%80%a6', '%e2%84%a2',
      // acute accents
      '%c2%b4', '%cb%8a', '%cc%81', '%cd%81',
      // grave accent, macron, caron
      '%cc%80', '%cc%84', '%cc%8c',
    ), '', $title );

    // Convert times to x
    $title = str_replace( '%c3%97', 'x', $title );
  }

  $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
  $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
  $title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
  $title = trim($title, '-');

  return $title;
}

$title = '#PFW Alexander McQueen Spring/Summer 2015';
echo "title -> slug: \n". $title ." -> ". sanitize_title_with_dashes($title);
echo "\n\n";
$title = '«GQ»: Elyas M\'Barek gehört zu Männern des Jahres';
echo "title -> slug: \n". $title ." -> ". sanitize_title_with_dashes($title);
```

View online [example](http://codepad.org/5DO3DVjS).

Comment: Links to latest: [formatting.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/formatting.php) also [functions.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/functions.php)

Comment: Second example fails for me, returns `%c2%abgq%c2%bb-elyas-mbarek-geh%c3%b6rt-zu-m%c3%a4nnern-des-jahres`

Answer (score 7):

Don't use preg_replace for this. There's a php function built just for the task: strtr()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

Taken from the comments in the above link (and I tested it myself; it works:

```
function normalize ($string) {
    $table = array(
        'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Đ'=>'Dj', 'đ'=>'dj', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'Č'=>'C', 'č'=>'c', 'Ć'=>'C', 'ć'=>'c',
        'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
        'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O',
        'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss',
        'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c', 'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e',
        'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o',
        'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b',
        'ÿ'=>'y', 'Ŕ'=>'R', 'ŕ'=>'r',
    );

    return strtr($string, $table);
}
```

Comment: the translation is ok, the problem is that im using the function through an ajax call, and it doesn't work in there =(

Comment: @andufo You must set charset in the ajax request.

Comment: This is only a partial answer to how to slugify a string.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't know which one to use so I made a quick bench on phptester.net

```
<?php

// First test
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/42740874/10232729
function slugify(STRING $string, STRING $separator = '-'){
    
    $accents_regex = '~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i';
    $special_cases = [ '&' => 'and', "'" => ''];
    $string = mb_strtolower( trim( $string ), 'UTF-8' );
    $string = str_replace( array_keys($special_cases), array_values( $special_cases), $string );
    $string = preg_replace( $accents_regex, '$1', htmlentities( $string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' ) );
    $string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/u', $separator, $string);
    
    return preg_replace('/['.$separator.']+/u', $separator, $string);
}

// Second test
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/13331948/10232729
function slug(STRING $string, STRING $separator = '-'){
    
    $string = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC; [:Punctuation:] Remove; Lower();', $string);
        
    return str_replace(' ', $separator, $string);;
}

// Third test - My choice
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/38066136/10232729
function slugbis($text){

    $replace = [
        '<' => '', '>' => '', '-' => ' ', '&' => '',
        '"' => '', 'À' => 'A', 'Á' => 'A', 'Â' => 'A', 'Ã' => 'A', 'Ä'=> 'Ae',
        'Ä' => 'A', 'Å' => 'A', 'Ā' => 'A', 'Ą' => 'A', 'Ă' => 'A', 'Æ' => 'Ae',
        'Ç' => 'C', 'Ć' => 'C', 'Č' => 'C', 'Ĉ' => 'C', 'Ċ' => 'C', 'Ď' => 'D', 'Đ' => 'D',
        'Ð' => 'D', 'È' => 'E', 'É' => 'E', 'Ê' => 'E', 'Ë' => 'E', 'Ē' => 'E',
        'Ę' => 'E', 'Ě' => 'E', 'Ĕ' => 'E', 'Ė' => 'E', 'Ĝ' => 'G', 'Ğ' => 'G',
        'Ġ' => 'G', 'Ģ' => 'G', 'Ĥ' => 'H', 'Ħ' => 'H', 'Ì' => 'I', 'Í' => 'I',
        'Î' => 'I', 'Ï' => 'I', 'Ī' => 'I', 'Ĩ' => 'I', 'Ĭ' => 'I', 'Į' => 'I',
        'İ' => 'I', 'Ĳ' => 'IJ', 'Ĵ' => 'J', 'Ķ' => 'K', 'Ł' => 'K', 'Ľ' => 'K',
        'Ĺ' => 'K', 'Ļ' => 'K', 'Ŀ' => 'K', 'Ñ' => 'N', 'Ń' => 'N', 'Ň' => 'N',
        'Ņ' => 'N', 'Ŋ' => 'N', 'Ò' => 'O', 'Ó' => 'O', 'Ô' => 'O', 'Õ' => 'O',
        'Ö' => 'Oe', 'Ö' => 'Oe', 'Ø' => 'O', 'Ō' => 'O', 'Ő' => 'O', 'Ŏ' => 'O',
        'Œ' => 'OE', 'Ŕ' => 'R', 'Ř' => 'R', 'Ŗ' => 'R', 'Ś' => 'S', 'Š' => 'S',
        'Ş' => 'S', 'Ŝ' => 'S', 'Ș' => 'S', 'Ť' => 'T', 'Ţ' => 'T', 'Ŧ' => 'T',
        'Ț' => 'T', 'Ù' => 'U', 'Ú' => 'U', 'Û' => 'U', 'Ü' => 'Ue', 'Ū' => 'U',
        'Ü' => 'Ue', 'Ů' => 'U', 'Ű' => 'U', 'Ŭ' => 'U', 'Ũ' => 'U', 'Ų' => 'U',
        'Ŵ' => 'W', 'Ý' => 'Y', 'Ŷ' => 'Y', 'Ÿ' => 'Y', 'Ź' => 'Z', 'Ž' => 'Z',
        'Ż' => 'Z', 'Þ' => 'T', 'à' => 'a', 'á' => 'a', 'â' => 'a', 'ã' => 'a',
        'ä' => 'ae', 'ä' => 'ae', 'å' => 'a', 'ā' => 'a', 'ą' => 'a', 'ă' => 'a',
        'æ' => 'ae', 'ç' => 'c', 'ć' => 'c', 'č' => 'c', 'ĉ' => 'c', 'ċ' => 'c',
        'ď' => 'd', 'đ' => 'd', 'ð' => 'd', 'è' => 'e', 'é' => 'e', 'ê' => 'e',
        'ë' => 'e', 'ē' => 'e', 'ę' => 'e', 'ě' => 'e', 'ĕ' => 'e', 'ė' => 'e',
        'ƒ' => 'f', 'ĝ' => 'g', 'ğ' => 'g', 'ġ' => 'g', 'ģ' => 'g', 'ĥ' => 'h',
        'ħ' => 'h', 'ì' => 'i', 'í' => 'i', 'î' => 'i', 'ï' => 'i', 'ī' => 'i',
        'ĩ' => 'i', 'ĭ' => 'i', 'į' => 'i', 'ı' => 'i', 'ĳ' => 'ij', 'ĵ' => 'j',
        'ķ' => 'k', 'ĸ' => 'k', 'ł' => 'l', 'ľ' => 'l', 'ĺ' => 'l', 'ļ' => 'l',
        'ŀ' => 'l', 'ñ' => 'n', 'ń' => 'n', 'ň' => 'n', 'ņ' => 'n', 'ŉ' => 'n',
        'ŋ' => 'n', 'ò' => 'o', 'ó' => 'o', 'ô' => 'o', 'õ' => 'o', 'ö' => 'oe',
        'ö' => 'oe', 'ø' => 'o', 'ō' => 'o', 'ő' => 'o', 'ŏ' => 'o', 'œ' => 'oe',
        'ŕ' => 'r', 'ř' => 'r', 'ŗ' => 'r', 'š' => 's', 'ù' => 'u', 'ú' => 'u',
        'û' => 'u', 'ü' => 'ue', 'ū' => 'u', 'ü' => 'ue', 'ů' => 'u', 'ű' => 'u',
        'ŭ' => 'u', 'ũ' => 'u', 'ų' => 'u', 'ŵ' => 'w', 'ý' => 'y', 'ÿ' => 'y',
        'ŷ' => 'y', 'ž' => 'z', 'ż' => 'z', 'ź' => 'z', 'þ' => 't', 'ß' => 'ss',
        'ſ' => 'ss', 'ый' => 'iy', 'А' => 'A', 'Б' => 'B', 'В' => 'V', 'Г' => 'G',
        'Д' => 'D', 'Е' => 'E', 'Ё' => 'YO', 'Ж' => 'ZH', 'З' => 'Z', 'И' => 'I',
        'Й' => 'Y', 'К' => 'K', 'Л' => 'L', 'М' => 'M', 'Н' => 'N', 'О' => 'O',
        'П' => 'P', 'Р' => 'R', 'С' => 'S', 'Т' => 'T', 'У' => 'U', 'Ф' => 'F',
        'Х' => 'H', 'Ц' => 'C', 'Ч' => 'CH', 'Ш' => 'SH', 'Щ' => 'SCH', 'Ъ' => '',
        'Ы' => 'Y', 'Ь' => '', 'Э' => 'E', 'Ю' => 'YU', 'Я' => 'YA', 'а' => 'a',
        'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', 'г' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e', 'ё' => 'yo',
        'ж' => 'zh', 'з' => 'z', 'и' => 'i', 'й' => 'y', 'к' => 'k', 'л' => 'l',
        'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n', 'о' => 'o', 'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r', 'с' => 's',
        'т' => 't', 'у' => 'u', 'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'c', 'ч' => 'ch',
        'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'sch', 'ъ' => '', 'ы' => 'y', 'ь' => '', 'э' => 'e',
        'ю' => 'yu', 'я' => 'ya'
    ];

    // make a human readable string
    $text = strtr($text, $replace);

    // replace non letter or digits by -
    $text = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d.]+~u', '-', $text);

    // trim
    $text = trim($text, '-');

    // remove unwanted characters
    $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w.]+~', '', $text);

    return strtolower($text);
}

// Fourth test
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/2955521/10232729
function slugagain($string){
    
    $table = [
        'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Đ'=>'Dj', 'đ'=>'dj', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'Č'=>'C', 'č'=>'c', 'Ć'=>'C', 'ć'=>'c',
        'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
        'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O',
        'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss',
        'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c', 'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e',
        'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o',
        'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b',
        'ÿ'=>'y', 'Ŕ'=>'R', 'ŕ'=>'r', ' '=>'-'
    ];

    return strtr($string, $table);
}

// Fifth test
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/27396804/10232729
function slugifybis($url){
    $url = trim($url);

    $url = str_replace(' ', '-', $url);
    $url = str_replace('/', '-slash-', $url);
    
    return rawurlencode($url);
}

// Sixth and last test
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/39442034/10232729
setlocale( LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF8" );  
function slugifyagain($string){
    
    $string = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//translit//ignore', $string); // transliterate
    $string = str_replace("'", '', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d]+~u', '-', $string); // replace non letter or non digits by "-"
    $string = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $string); // remove unwanted characters
    $string = preg_replace('~-+~', '-', $string); // remove duplicate "-"
    $string = trim($string, '-'); // trim "-"
    $string = trim($string); // trim
    $string = mb_strtolower($string, 'utf-8'); // lowercase
    
    return urlencode($string); // safe;
};

$string = $newString = "¿ Àñdréß l'affreux ğarçon & nøël en forêt !";

$max = 10000;

echo '<pre>';
echo 'Beginning :';
echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';    
echo '> Slugging '.$max.' iterations of following :';
echo '<br />';
echo '>> ' . $string;
echo '<br />';  
echo '<br />';
echo 'Output results :';
echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';  

$start = microtime(true);

for($i = 0 ; $i < $max ; $i++){
    
    $newString = slugify($string);
}

$time = (microtime(true) - $start) * 1000;

echo '> First test passed in **' . round($time, 2) . 'ms**';
echo '<br />';  
echo '>> Result : ' . $newString;
echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';

$start = microtime(true);

for($i = 0 ; $i < $max ; $i++){
    
    $newString = slug($string);
}

$time = (microtime(true) - $start) * 1000;

echo '> Second test passed in **' . round($time, 2) . 'ms**';
echo '<br />';
echo '>> Result : ' . $newString;
echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';

$start = microtime(true);

for($i = 0 ; $i < $max ; $i++){
    
    $newString = slugbis($string);
}

$time = (microtime(true) - $start) * 1000;

echo '> Third test passed in **' . round($time, 2) . 'ms**';
echo '<br />';
echo '>> Result : ' . $newString;
echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';

$start = microtime(true);

for($i = 0 ; $i < $max ; $i++){
    
    $newString = slugagain($string);
}

$time = (microtime(true) - $start) * 1000;

echo '> Fourth test passed in **' . round($time, 2) . 'ms**';
echo '<br />';
echo '>> Result : ' . $newString;
echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';

$start = microtime(true);

for($i = 0 ; $i < $max ; $i++){
    
    $newString = slugifybis($string);
}

$time = (microtime(true) - $start) * 1000;

echo '> Fifth test passed in **' . round($time, 2) . 'ms**';
echo '<br />';
echo '>> Result : ' . $newString;
echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';

$start = microtime(true);

for($i = 0 ; $i < $max ; $i++){
    
    $newString = slugifyagain($string);
}

$time = (microtime(true) - $start) * 1000;

echo '> Sixth test passed in **' . round($time, 2) . 'ms**';
echo '<br />';
echo '>> Result : ' . $newString;
echo '</pre>';
```

Beginning :

> Slugging 10000 iterations of following :
>
> > ¿ Àñdréß l'affreux ğarçon & nøël en forêt !

Output results :

> First test passed in **120.78ms**
>
> > Result : -iquest-andresz-laffreux-arcon-and-noel-en-foret-
>
> Second test passed in **3883.82ms**
>
> > Result : -andreß-laffreux-garcon--nøel-en-foret-
>
> Third test passed in **56.83ms**
>
> > Result : andress-l-affreux-garcon-noel-en-foret
>
> Fourth test passed in **18.93ms**
>
> > Result : ¿-AndreSs-l'affreux-ğarcon-&-noel-en-foret-!
>
> Fifth test passed in **6.45ms**
>
> > Result : %C2%BF-%C3%80%C3%B1dr%C3%A9%C3%9F-l%27affreux-%C4%9Far%C3%A7on-%26-n%C3%B8%C3%ABl-en-for%C3%AAt-%21
>
> Sixth test passed in **112.42ms**
>
> > Result : andress-laffreux-garcon-n-el-en-foret

Further tests needed.

Edit : less iterations test

Beginning :

> Slugging 100 iterations of following :
>
> > ¿ Àñdréß l'affreux ğarçon & nøël en forêt !

Output results :

> First test passed in **1.72ms**
>
> > Result : -iquest-andresz-laffreux-arcon-and-noel-en-foret-
>
> Second test passed in **48.59ms**
>
> > Result : -andreß-laffreux-garcon--nøel-en-foret-
>
> Third test passed in **0.91ms**
>
> > Result : andress-l-affreux-garcon-noel-en-foret
>
> Fourth test passed in **0.3ms**
>
> > Result : ¿-AndreSs-l'affreux-ğarcon-&-noel-en-foret-!
>
> Fifth test passed in **0.14ms**
>
> > Result : %C2%BF-%C3%80%C3%B1dr%C3%A9%C3%9F-l%27affreux-%C4%9Far%C3%A7on-%26-n%C3%B8%C3%ABl-en-for%C3%AAt-%21
>
> Sixth test passed in **1.4ms**
>
> > Result : andress-laffreux-garcon-n-el-en-foret

Answer (score 5):

I am using:

```
function slugify($text)
{ 
    $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
    return strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $text));
}
```

Only fallback is that Cyrillic characters will not be converted, and I am searching now for solution that is not long str_replace for every single Cyrillic character.

Comment: iconv is not installed on many servers. solution to convert any characters is to use `set_locale('cyrillic.UTF-8')` first. Exact value depends on your installed locales.

Answer (score 4):

The most elegant way I think is using a Behat\Transliterator\Transliterator.

I need to extends this class by your class because it is an Abstract, some like this:

```
<?php
use Behat\Transliterator\Transliterator;

class Urlizer extends Transliterator
{
}
```

And then, just use it:

```
$text = "Master Ápiu";
$urlizer = new Urlizer();
$slug = $urlizer->transliterate($slug, "-");
echo $slug; // master-apiu
```

Of course you should put this things in your composer as well.

```
composer require behat/transliterator
```

More info here https://github.com/Behat/Transliterator

Answer (score 3):

This may be a way to do it too. Inspired from these links [Experts-exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25729563/Remove-accents-in-a-UTF-8-string-PHP.html) and [alinalexander](https://alvinalexander.com/php/php-string-strip-characters-whitespace-numbers)

```
function slugifier($txt){

   /* Get rid of accented characters */
   $search = explode(",","ç,æ,œ,á,é,í,ó,ú,à,è,ì,ò,ù,ä,ë,ï,ö,ü,ÿ,â,ê,î,ô,û,å,e,i,ø,u");
   $replace = explode(",","c,ae,oe,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,y,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u");
   $txt = str_replace($search, $replace, $txt);

   /* Lowercase all the characters */
   $txt = strtolower($txt);

   /* Avoid whitespace at the beginning and the ending */
   $txt = trim($txt);

   /* Replace all the characters that are not in a-z or 0-9 by a hyphen */
   $txt = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]/", "-", $txt);
   /* Remove hyphen anywhere it's more than one */
   $txt = preg_replace("/[\-]+/", '-', $txt);
   return $txt;   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function slugify($text)
{
    // replace non letter or digits by -
    $text = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);
    // transliterate
    $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
    // remove unwanted characters
    $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);
    // trim
    $text = trim($text, '-');
    // remove duplicate -
    $text = preg_replace('~-+~', '-', $text);
    // lowercase
    $text = strtolower($text);
    if (empty($text)) {
        return 'n-a';
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Use case:

```
echo slugify('bu metinde ç ö ş ğ ü ı * # karakter $ @ ! ?  kullanılamaz');
```

Output: `bu-metinde-c-o-s-g-u-i-karakter-kullanilamaz`

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at `Normalizer::normalize()`, [see here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php). It just needs to load the intl module for PHP

Answer (score 2):

What about using something that is already implemented in Core?

```
//Clean non UTF-8 characters    
Mage::getHelper('core/string')->cleanString($str)
```

Or one of the core url/ url rewrite methods..

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this based on Maerlyn's response. This function will work regardless of the character encoding on the page. It also won't turn single quotes in to dashes :)

```
function slugify ($string) {
    $string = utf8_encode($string);
    $string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);   
    $string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9- ]/i', '', $string);
    $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string);
    $string = trim($string, '-');
    $string = strtolower($string);

    if (empty($string)) {
        return 'n-a';
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Yay this one actually works, that was really bugging me turning apostrophes/single quotes into hyphens. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On my localhost everything was ok, but on server it helped me “set_locale” and “utf-8” at “mb_strtolower”.

```
<?
setlocale( LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF8" );
function slug( $str, $char = "-", $tf = "lowercase" )
{
    $str = iconv( "utf-8", "us-ascii//translit//ignore", $str ); // transliterate
    $str = str_replace( "'", "", $str ); // remove “'” generated by iconv
    $str = preg_replace( "~[^a-z0-9]+~ui", $char, $str ); // replace unwanted by single “-”
    $str = trim( $str, $char ); // trim “-”
    if( $tf == "lowercase" ) $str = mb_strtolower( $str, "utf-8" ); // lowercase
    elseif( $tf == "uppercase" ) $str = mb_strtoupper( $str, "utf-8" );
    return $str;
}
?>
```

Test

```
$string = "--+ěščřžýá091354--––—_-6íé↨☻☻ßẞąć …   ęłńśźżĄĆ  ĘŁŃŚ   Ź///+++||||..Ż";
echo slug( $string );
echo slug( $string, "☻", "uppercase" );

// → escrzya091354-6iessac-elnszzac-elns-z-z
// → ESCRZYA091354☻6IESSAC☻ELNSZZAC☻ELNS☻Z☻Z
```

Comment: its for latin extended ěščřžýáíéúůó

Answer (score 1):

There's a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9535967/2056484) that deals with special characters as well.

Texto Fantástico => texto-fantastico

```
function slugify( $string, $separator = '-' ) {
    $accents_regex = '~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i';
    $special_cases = array( '&' => 'and', "'" => '');
    $string = mb_strtolower( trim( $string ), 'UTF-8' );
    $string = str_replace( array_keys($special_cases), array_values( $special_cases), $string );
    $string = preg_replace( $accents_regex, '$1', htmlentities( $string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' ) );
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]/u", "$separator", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[$separator]+/u", "$separator", $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Author: Natxet

Answer (score 1):

For standard alphanumeric english - nothing complicated.

```
/**
 * Update the provided string to a slug-safe format.
 *
 * @param string $string
 * @return string
 */
function slugify($string)
{
    return strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $string), '-'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it works for every cases but i took the slug method from Laravel [Str class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php#L954) and added the `iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $title)` thing to treat accents without the need to use [`voku/portable-ascii`](https://github.com/voku/portable-ascii) it seems to work pretty well for my use cases :

```php
    public static function slug($title, $separator = '-')
    {
        $title = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $title);
        $flip = $separator === '-' ? '_' : '-';
        $title = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote($flip).']+!u', $separator, $title);
        // Replace @ with the word 'at'
        $title = str_replace('@', $separator.'at'.$separator, $title);
        // Remove all characters that are not the separator, letters, numbers, or whitespace.
        $title = preg_replace('![^'.preg_quote($separator).'\pL\pN\s]+!u', '', mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8'));
        // Replace all separator characters and whitespace by a single separator
        $title = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote($separator).'\s]+!u', $separator, $title);

        return trim($title, $separator);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 8 it's:

```
Str::slug('Hola como te va', '-');

// hola-como-te-va
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [gTLDs](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/delegated-strings) and [IDNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) are becoming more and more used I cannot see why URL shouldn't contain Andrés.

Just rawurlencode $URL you want instead. Most browsers show UTF-8 characters in URLs (not some ancient IE6 maybe) and bit.ly / goo.gl can be used to make it short in cases like Russian and Arabic if need may be for ad purposes or just write them in ads like user would write them on browser URL.

Only difference is spaces " " it might be good idea to replace them with "-" and "/" if you don't want to allow those.

```
<?php
function slugify($url)
{
    $url = trim($url);

    $url = str_replace(" ","-",$url);
    $url = str_replace("/","-slash-",$url);
    $url = rawurlencode($url);
}
?>
```

Url as encoded 
http://www.hurtta.com/RU/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B/

Url as written [http://www.hurtta.com/RU/Продукты/](http://www.hurtta.com/RU/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B/)

Answer (score 0):

Since I've Seen a lot of methods here but I've found a simplest method for myself.Maybe it will help someone.

```
$slug = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/', '',preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $string) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short and easy solution for making slug

```
function convertURLs($value){
$delimiter = '-';
$slug = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', $delimiter, preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', $delimiter, preg_replace('/[&]/', 'and', preg_replace('/[\']/', '', iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $value))))), $delimiter));
return $slug;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this function and it works fine:

```
function slugify($string) {
  return strtolower(trim(preg_replace('~[^0-9a-z]+~i', '-', html_entity_decode(preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), '-'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to using `urldecode` to get the decoded string:

```php
echo urldecode('%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C%DA%A9'); 

// return السلام-علیک
```

Answer (score -1):

For me this variant is perfect, also it change `&` to `and`. Here is code:

```
function dSlug($string) {
    return strtolower(trim(preg_replace('~[^0-9a-z]+~i', '-', html_entity_decode(preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1',htmlentities(preg_replace('/[&]/', ' and ', $title), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), '-'));
}`
```

Answer (score -1):

if your slug contain only A-Za-z0-9- then it is ok for you

```php
function sanitize_slug($text)
{
    $text = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $text);
    $text = trim($text, '-');
    $text = preg_replace('~-+~', '-', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Vous pouvez cette function pour transformer ton title en url
function slug($string, $delimiter = '-') {
    $oldLocale = setlocale(LC_ALL, '0');
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');
    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower($clean);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);
    $clean = trim($clean, $delimiter);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $oldLocale);
    return $clean;
}
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer