# Convert string into slug with single-hyphen delimiters only

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, slug, sanitization

I would  like to sanitize a string in to a URL so this is what I basically need:

1. Everything must be removed except alphanumeric characters and spaces and dashed.
2. Spaces should be converter into dashes.

Eg.

```
This, is the URL!
```

must return

```
this-is-the-url
```

Comment: Hi jens, I am clueless about the code and thats what I need help for. The only thing I know is it should use preg_replace() but I dont know what the regular expression should be. Thanks

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
function slug($z){
    $z = strtolower($z);
    $z = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 -]+/', '', $z);
    $z = str_replace(' ', '-', $z);
    return trim($z, '-');
}
```

Comment: great thanks.. Just one edit.. I want to remove dashes from beginning and end before returning $z just in case they exists.

Comment: -1: Reading between the lines of what SilentGhost *intends* rather than the code he/she has written. this appears url-safe, it's at the cost of loss of information. The right way to encode data for a URL is to use urlencode().

Comment: (I see it does the translation shown in the example - but not what atif089 asked for)

Comment: @symcbean: most people on board of this planetary ship are not comfortable `urldecode`-ing on the fly.

Comment: @symcbean urlecode is not what I needed because I want to eliminate symbols rather than converting them. So this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: shorter: strtolower(trim(preg_replace("/[^\w]+/", "-", $z), "-"))

Comment: @mario: 1. it doesn't do the same processing; 2. it's a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 4):

First strip unwanted characters

```
$new_string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $string);
```

Then changes spaces for unserscores

```
$url = preg_replace('/\s/', '-', $new_string);
```

Finally encode it ready for use

```
$new_url = urlencode($url);
```

Comment: underscore is a different character: `_` is an underscore, `-` is a hyphen. Also using `urlencode` on such a string doesn't change anything. You're also forgetting hypen in the first regex and `\s` is not equivalent to space character.

Answer (score 2):

The OP is not explicitly describing all of the attributes of a slug, but this is what I am gathering from the intent.

My interpretation of a perfect, valid, condensed slug aligns with this post: [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149191/slug-formatting-acceptable-characters#:~:text=However%2C%20we%20can%20summarise%20the,or%20end%20with%20a%20hyphen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149191/slug-formatting-acceptable-characters#:%7E:text=However%2C%20we%20can%20summarise%20the,or%20end%20with%20a%20hyphen).

I find none of the earlier posted answers to achieve this consistently (and I'm not even stretching the scope of the question to include multi-byte characters).

1. convert all characters to lowercase
2. replace all sequences of one or more non-alphanumeric characters to a single hyphen.
3. trim the leading and trailing hyphens from the string.

I recommend the following one-liner which doesn't bother declaring single-use variables:

```
return trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/', '-', strtolower($string)), '-');
```

Not shown in my demo link, here is an attempt to better handle multibyte strings, though it doesn't quite accommodate as many scenarios as Casimir's answer.

```
return trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/', '-', strtolower(iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//translit', $string))), '-');
```

I have also prepared a demonstration which highlights what I consider to be inaccuracies in the other answers. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/brB6T))

```
'This, is - - the URL!' input
'this-is-the-url'       expected

'this-is-----the-url'   SilentGhost
'this-is-the-url'       mario
'This-is---the-URL'     Rooneyl
'This-is-the-URL'       AbhishekGoel
'This, is - - the URL!' HelloHack
'This, is - - the URL!' DenisMatafonov
'This,-is-----the-URL!' AdeelRazaAzeemi
'this-is-the-url'       mickmackusa

---
'Mork & Mindy'      input
'mork-mindy'        expected

'mork--mindy'       SilentGhost
'mork-mindy'        mario
'Mork--Mindy'       Rooneyl
'Mork-Mindy'        AbhishekGoel
'Mork &amp; Mindy'  HelloHack
'Mork & Mindy'      DenisMatafonov
'Mork-&-Mindy'      AdeelRazaAzeemi
'mork-mindy'        mickmackusa

---
'What the_underscore ?!?'   input
'what-the-underscore'       expected

'what-theunderscore'        SilentGhost
'what-the_underscore'       mario
'What-theunderscore-'       Rooneyl
'What-theunderscore-'       AbhishekGoel
'What the_underscore ?!?'   HelloHack
'What the_underscore ?!?'   DenisMatafonov
'What-the_underscore-?!?'   AdeelRazaAzeemi
'what-the-underscore'       mickmackusa
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it in a Unix shell (I just tried it on my MacOS):

```
$ tr -cs A-Za-z '-' < infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

I got the idea from a blog post on [More Shell, Less Egg](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2011/12/more-shell-less-egg/.)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 function clean($string) {
       $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
       $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.

       return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string); // Replaces multiple hyphens with single one.
    }
```

Usage:

```
echo clean('a|"bc!@£de^&$f g');
```

Will output: `abcdef-g`

source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14114419/2439715

Answer (score 1):

Using [intl transliterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php) is a good option because with it you can easily handle complicated cases with a single set of rules. I added custom rules to illustrate how it can be flexible and how you can keep a maximum of meaningful informations. Feel free to remove them and to add your own rules.

```
$strings = [
    'This, is - - the URL!',
    'Holmes & Yoyo',
    'L’Œil de démon',
    'How to win 1000€?',
    '€, $ ＆ other currency symbols',
    'Und die Katze fraß alle mäuse.',
    'Белите рози на София',
    'പോണ്ടിച്ചേരി സൂര്യനു കീഴിൽ',
];

$rules = <<<'RULES'
# Transliteration
:: Any-Latin ;   :: Latin-Ascii ;

# examples of custom replacements
'&' > ' and ' ;
[^0-9][01]? { € > ' euro' ;   € > ' euros' ;
[^0-9][01]? { '$' > ' dollar' ;   '$' > ' dollars' ;
:: Null ;

# slugify
[^[:alnum:]&[:ascii:]]+ > '-' ;
:: Lower ;

# trim
[$] { '-' > &Remove() ;
'-' } [$] > &Remove() ;
RULES;

$tsl = Transliterator::createFromRules($rules, Transliterator::FORWARD);
$results = array_map(fn($s) => $tsl->transliterate($s), $strings);
print_r($results);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/FF64S)

Unfortunately, the PHP manual is totally empty about ICU transformations but you can find informations about them [here](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/transforms/).

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13331948/2943403

Answer (score 0):

All previous asnwers deal with url, but in case some one will need to sanitize string for login (e.g.) and keep it as text, here is you go:

```
function sanitizeText($str) {
    $withSpecCharacters = htmlspecialchars($str);
    $splitted_str = str_split($str);
    $result = '';
    foreach ($splitted_str as $letter){
        if (strpos($withSpecCharacters, $letter) !== false) {
            $result .= $letter;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

echo sanitizeText('ОРРииыфвсси ajvnsakjvnHB "&nvsp;\n" <script>alert()</script>');
//ОРРииыфвсси ajvnsakjvnHB &nvsp;\n scriptalert()/script
//No injections possible, all info at max keeped
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function isolate($data) {
        
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Please add more information with your code, maybe how to use or how you got to this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The following will replace spaces with dashes.

```
$str = str_replace(' ', '-', $str);
```

Then the following statement will remove everything except alphanumeric characters and dashed. (didn't have spaces because in previous step we had replaced them with dashes.

```
// Char representation     0 -  9   A-   Z   a-   z  -    
$str = preg_replace('/[^\x30-\x39\x41-\x5A\x61-\x7A\x2D]/', '', $str);
```

Which is equivalent to

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^0-9A-Za-z-]+/', '', $str);
```

FYI: To remove all special characters from a string use

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^\x20-\x7E]/', '', $str);
```

\x20 is hexadecimal for space that is start of Acsii charecter and \x7E is tilde. As accordingly to wikipedia [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

FYI: look into the Hex Column for the interval 20-7E

Printable characters
Codes 20hex to 7Ehex, known as the printable characters, represent letters, digits, punctuation marks, and a few miscellaneous symbols. There are 95 printable characters in total.

Comment: I can challenge anyone to proof me wrong. Don't know why i was downvoted.

Comment: Demonstrations can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65280956/2943403

Answer (score -1):

You should use the slugify package and not reinvent the wheel ;)

https://github.com/cocur/slugify

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.
Can you elaborate on this a little more?