# PHP internal encoding

Tags: php, encoding

According to bin2hex my PHP is internally using UTF-8:

```
echo bin2hex("ö"); -> c3b6 (utf-8)
echo bin2hex(utf8_decode("ö")); -> f6 (ISO-8859)
```

But both mb_internal_encoding() and iconv_get_encoding() say it is ISO-8859-1.

```
echo mb_internal_encoding(); -> ISO-8859-1
var_dump(iconv_get_encoding()); ->  ["input_encoding"]=>  string(10) "ISO-8859-1"  ["output_encoding"]=>  string(10) "ISO-8859-1"  ["internal_encoding"]=>  string(10) "ISO-8859-1"
```

UTF-8 seems to apparently be the one it's using, but why is it showing ISO-8859-1 anyway?

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/151296 This is a good explanation regarding PHP and usage of UTF-8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not strange at all. Your first check is for what is between the quotes. I assume you have *saved* the file using UTF-8 which means you have two bytes in your string. This does not imply that the internal encoding is UTF-8, just that you have those two bytes in you string.

Comment: Oh, right. For what is the internal encoding getting used at all?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on it, always explicitly state the encoding.

Comment: @Sven What's the best method of doing so?

Comment: All mb_string functions have a parameter to specify the encoding used. The same applies to iconv. Never rely on an internal setting to be right, always explicitply pass "UTF-8" as encoding.

Comment: If I am using UTF-8 in PHP, I must always use the mb_ safe functions, right?

Answer (score 4):

This is a default setting in **php.ini** :

```
[iconv]
;iconv.input_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.internal_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.output_encoding = ISO-8859-1
```

If you want to use UTF-8 everywhere you should use these settings :

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"

[iconv]
iconv.input_encoding = UTF-8
iconv.internal_encoding = UTF-8
iconv.output_encoding = UTF-8

[mbstring]
mbstring.language = Neutral
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
mbstring.http_input = auto
mbstring.http_output = UTF-8
mbstring.encoding_translation = On
mbstring.detect_order = auto
mbstring.substitute_character = none;
```