# Creating slug with strtolower() and preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, clean-urls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular Expression Sanitize (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022185/regular-expression-sanitize-php)

I want to make my links SEO. Before I started the links looked like this:

```
http://www.domain.tld/index.php?page=blog
```

My goal was to change it to: `http://www.domain.tld/blog`. That works now.

I changed the htaccess to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^\w+$ index.php?page=$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(\d+)-([\w-]+)$ index.php?page=single_news&id=$1&headline=$2
```

Now I want to change the URIs of the headlines of any blog entry. They looked like this: `http://www.domain.tld/index.php?page=single_news&id=2&headline=This%20Is%20A%20Headline`

I want to make them looking like this: `http://www.domain.tld/blog/2-this-is-a-headline`
I am generating my headline-links in the div-class "news_headline" (see below).

```
<div id="main">
<?php
$query = "SELECT `id`, `headline`, `writer`, `content`, DATE_FORMAT(date,\"%d. %M %Y\") AS `date` FROM `blog` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$news_resource = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>

<?php
$all_news = array();
$five_news = array();
for($i = 0; $news = mysql_fetch_object($news_resource); $i++){
if($i < 5){
  $five_news[] = $news;
}
$all_news[] = $news;
}
?>

<?php foreach($five_news as $news)
{ ?>

<div class="news_bg">
<div class="news_headline"><a href="blog/<?php echo $news->id; ?>-<?php echo $news->headline; ?>"><?php echo $news->headline; ?></a></div>
<div class="news_infoline_top"><?php echo $news->date; ?> &middot; <?php echo $news->writer; ?></div>
<div class="news_text"><?php echo $news->content; ?></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

With my htaccess (see above) the links are like this now:

```
http://www.domain.tld/blog/2-This Is A Headline
```

I already had help about this and a good guy gave me this code-snippets to make the links looking like I want, but I don't know how to use them:

```
$urititle = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^\w-]+/','-', $title));
```

and

```
$_GET['headline'] != $urititle
```

I am lost.

Comment: Just some notes: 5 News is [`LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0` in SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html). Query that from the database directly. Then a small mistake: You don't query *title* from the database but *headline*. Fix that. The next thing you need to do in your loop is to turn the title into it's [*"slug"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(web_publishing)) which you should put into a function of it's own (like `slugify($news->title)`).

Comment: What exactly is your question?!

Comment: …or you just use some existing function to do so, e.g. Textpatterns `dumbDown()` function, which "transliterates a string to ASCII". See: http://textpattern.googlecode.com/svn/development/4.x/textpattern/lib/txplib_misc.php

Comment: @SalmanA How do I get my links like this? `http://www.domain.tld/blog/2-this-is-a-headline`

Comment: @hakre There is no _title_ in my database. The mistake was in my echo. I changed it to _headline_ now. Now the links looks like this `http://www.domain.tld/blog/2-This Is A Headline`

Comment: Yes, thought so because before it was empty. Edit your question so that little mistake is removed already. Have you seen the link by @SilentGhost? I think that is what you're looking for.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already pretty close:

- You put the ID to the beginning of the intersting part. That allows you to query your database by the ID which is unique *and* fast.
- You have the understanding that you need to transform the text of the headline into the *slug* variant of it and you already know that this is string processing.

You have some steps left to finish this. Somme notes:

- Create yourself a function that does the string transformation. The important part here is, that you can call it simply.
- When the request to an article comes in, fetch the article based on the ID value you obtain from the string: `$assigned = sscanf($slug, '%d-', $id);`
- For SEO, do the same as when creating the link. Then compare if the current link *still* is correct (the headline might have changed). If not, do a permanent redirect to the correct link.

And that's it!