# Display download button after user details are submitted via web form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I understand I'm meant to put my ideas of how this could work, but I'm unable to do so as I'm trying to understand the best approach. I've not had any ideas from the "programmers" site so I need to try an other approach.

I've searched google, but must be using the wrong terms..

I'm trying to find a plugin or script that lets me capture basic user info like name, company and email address. After they complete and send this (With basic validation performed) the site will show a download button which lets them download a pdf.

I'm stuck where to start, so just looking for some help to point me in the right direction.

An alternative approach is for an automatic email to be fired after the user data has been submitted.

Sites being built in html/css so ideal I'd like to know if there is something using Javascript I can use or if really needed php would be my preferred option.

Thanks for your understanding about this request.

Comment: You'd want to use PHP, as anything client-side could be circumvented without as much as a blink. You have to show some effort code-wise here of where you got stuck to get anymore help.

Comment: there are dozens or hundreds of web application technologies that can be applied for your case. Take any good tutorial on PHP to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a few links to get you started

- [Form Handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)
- [String Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string)
- [Sending Mail](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)

PDF creation is a little bit more advanced but if your up for the challenge I use a class called [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)

Hopefully this will get you started!