# How to delete wrong symbols and wrong length strings from string array?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have such array:

```
$array = array('abC12', 'bC44', 'Am286c$', 'cC092', 'cC09288');
```

With using rexexp it is necessary to, at first, delete symbols (replace by ''), that are not in [A-Ca-c0-9].
At second, it is necessary to delete from array variables that not match such condition:
string length not equal to 5 (values 'bC44' and 'cC09288').

So, as result array must contain:

```
$array = array('abC12', 'A286c', 'cC092');
```

Thanks you for any help!

Vladimir.

Comment: I tried, for example this: $array = preg_replace('/^[a-c0-9]{5}$/i', '', $array);

Comment: ok,you can take help from this for replacing symbols and spaces in the string
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $val) {
    $val = preg_replace('/[^a-c0-9]/i', '', $val); // Remove symbols
    if (strlen($val) == 5) { // Check string length
        $result[] = $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Barmar, thanks you very much! Is it possible to use only preg_replace (somehow with {32})? So not to use if block

Comment: `preg_replace` just returns the updated string, it won't have any effect on whether the string is put in `$result`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$array = array('abC12', 'bC44', 'Am286c$', 'cC092', 'cC09288');
$array = array_filter(preg_replace('/[^a-c0-9]/i', '',$array),function ($var) {return strlen($var) == 5;});
print_r($array);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => abC12
    [2] => A286c
    [3] => cC092
)
```

preg_replace acts also on array.
Documentation [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)