# How can I restrict some special characters only in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match, pcre

I am using preg_match for restrict the special characters in form post. Now I need to restrict some special characters only like `%,$,#,*` and I need to post like `bé`. How to possible to restrict some special characters only.

My code:

```
<?php
$firstname='';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
    if(preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", $firstname))
    {
    echo 'Invalid Name';
    }
    else
    {
    echo $firstname;
    }

}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="firstname"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14114419/466082

Comment: I suggest allowing `-` as a character in firstnames.... haven't you every heard of `Jean-Claude Van Damme`? Though I can't think of any first names that contain numbers off the top of my head

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```regex
([%\$#\*]+)
```

to match those characters.

So in `preg_match` you should use:

```php
if(preg_match("/([%\$#\*]+)/", $firstname))
{
   echo 'Invalid Name';
}
else
{
   echo $firstname;
}
```

Comment: So, `(^_^;)` is a valid name?

Comment: @georg Of course not, but OP wanted only restrict selected characters

Comment: Look, your code is quite different from what the OP has, because he (correctly) whitelists, and you blacklist. Blacklisting never works.

Answer (score 3):

Blacklisting (=enumerating *invalid* characters) is not an option in the unicode world. Consider for example, a "name" like this:

Ж☝ⓚƒ

You don't really want to blacklist all of these.

A whitelisting approach is, on the contrary, quite simple using the `u` mode and unicode properties:

```
var_dump(preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{N}]+$/u', 'ßäßå'));  // 1
var_dump(preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{N}]+$/u', 'r2d2'));  // 1
var_dump(preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{N}]+$/u', 'w#t?'));  // 0
var_dump(preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{N}]+$/u', 'Ж☝ⓚƒ'));  // 0
```

And since we're talking about validating real names, please read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) before you start complicating things.

Comment: You could add some punctuations like `'` or `-` for `O'Connors` or `Jean-François`

Comment: @M42: the linked article is quite helpful and entertaining - read it!

Comment: Sure, I've already read it, I just said it may have punctuation in name.

Comment: @M42: I understand. The thing is, if we start adding punctation, we should do this correctly (to disallow things like `O'O'Connor`) and then our assumptions about the structure will turn out wrong (they will do), and this is a never-ending story. There's no algorithm to validate every possible human name.