# How to remove specific expression from an array

Tags: php

How to remove specific expression from an array

Remove the following element

```
$value['#434434*siva']
```

**Output :**

```
434434siva
```

Comment: Can you be some more clear, want the array keys with special characters removed?

Comment: do you mean, "how to remove specific character set from elements of a list?"

Comment: `preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]*/i', '', '#434434*siva')` if you only want to keep the alpha-numeric chars

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string)` to remove all the special characters

```
<?php
    function clean($string) 
    {
        return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
    }
?>
```

Then for array, you can do it like:

```
<?php
    foreach($value as $val)
        clean($val);
?>
```

Source: [Remove all special characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]*/', '#434434*siva')

only digit and