# PHP - Removing Brackets and Special Characters

Tags: php, string, special-characters

I'm looking to modify a PHP string so I can use it as an anchor tag.

I used the method found here: [Remove all special characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string)

It worked well to remove ampersands from my strings, but it doesn't seem to be removing or affecting the brackets or punctuation.

Here's what I'm currently using:

```
$name_clean = preg_replace('/ [^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $name); // REMOVES SPECIAL CHARACTERS
$name_slug = str_replace(' ', '-', $name_clean); // REPLACES SPACES WITH DASHES IN TITLE
$link = strtolower( $name_slug ); // CREATES LOWERCASE SLUG VERSION OF TITLE_SLUG
```

My string (in this case $name) = St. John's (Newfoundland).

The output I get = #st.-john'snewfoundland)

I'd like to remove the periods, apostrophes and brackets altogether.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the leading space in the regex intentional?

Comment: It was, because originally the only character I was trying to affect was an ampersand that always followed a space. With a few adjustments I was able to get it working though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex pattern `/ [^A-Za-z0-9\-]/` appears to contain a space after the opening `/`.  This pattern will only match a special character that comes after a space.  Removing that space should get the result you want.

Comment: Aha! Thank you for that.