# I want to escape all characters possible and not just the ones predefined in mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm currently using mysqli_real_escape_string. It is working fine but I want to know whether there is a function more *broader*, which will escape more characters than the predefined ones like ',",\r etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string

Comment: I have tried addslashes() too, but its almost the same as mysqli_real_escape_string()

Comment: Why not use [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Every character can be escaped, but based on what you said (inserting that string with the single quote), that's not what you want. With real_escape_string that will get correctly escaped. So what's your actual problem?

Comment: Note that was a response to a comment of OP that was deleted afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

You should treat the data depending on it's context.

So when you put it in a mysql database you want to treat it so it does not interfere with the internal processes.

When you want to output the data in a browser you treat it so it can not be processed in a way it is not meant to. By just 'randomly' escaping everything you are just distorting data.

But if you really want to... I guess you could use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), or [addcslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php) to build your own 'escaping' function. You just have to define those charakters you want to escape (and then search and replace them with '\'+the charakter, in case of preg_- and str_replace).

If you don't want to just escape every data but it is about getting the string correctly into the database you might want to just use Prepared Statements. They work a little different from normal queries so the values don't have to be treated in a specific way. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php