# How can transform an string with special characters

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.5

I have following string :
`src=//myServer.dev/test1/test2/loader.swf`. Is it possible to transform this string in : `%2F%%2F%myServer.dev%2Ftest1%2Ftest2%2Floader.swf` ?

In fact I need to transform all special characters in their code.
Help me

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: i think you look for htmlspecialchars : http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php ?

Comment: [Take a look at this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string) I think this has been answered before

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using PHP's [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) method.