# PHP Regex for highlight string

Tags: php, regex, search, highlight, keyword

I need a script to highlight occurrences of one or more keywords in a text. I have a script in French and I want my script to look for occurrences with special characters and uppercase letters.

My URL is (example): .../?q=être

And I wish the keywords "être", "Être", "etre" and "Etre" to be highlighted.

Is it possible ? (with `<mark>...</mark>`)

Example :

```xml
Bonjour ceci est un texte avec le verbe <mark>être</mark>, avec la majuscule ça aurait
été <mark>Être</mark>, et sans accent <mark>etre</mark>, puis <mark>Etre</mark>.
```

So:

- Ignore specials characters
- Ignore uppercase

Comment: Your description and examples don't match up. `Ignore specials characters - Ignore uppercase`...`I wish the keywords "être", "Être", "etre" and "Etre" to be highlighted`. Those have special characters and uppercase letters. You also should provide an example of what you've tried.

Comment: Yep, i want to on my URL i have "être", "Être", "etre" and "Etre", and i want to on my string target, the word(s) "être", "Être", "etre" and "Etre" to be highlight.
So i want to ignore specials chars and uppercase on all request :)

Comment: `ê` is a special character, `Ê` is special and uppercase... or do you mean any form of `etre`?

Comment: And if the search word is `"etre"` *(without accent)*, do you want also words with accent to be highlighted?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Looks like it should be a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string.

Comment: @chris85: I don't think, the goal isn't to sanitize the string but to find (and highlight) a word with or without accent, and this without to change the accents of the original string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This sample will match with the required words in your sentence:

*And I wish the keywords "**être**", "**Être**", "**etre**" and "**Etre**" to be highlighted.*

```
/[êÊeE]tre/
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want ALL specials characters, and ALL uppercase. Not just for "être". Thanks you :)

Comment: Could you write me here the ALL special characters what you would like? :)

Answer (score -1):

I, i think :

```
$utf8 = array(
        '/[áàâãªä]/u'   =>   'a',
        '/[ÁÀÂÃÄ]/u'    =>   'A',
        '/[ÍÌÎÏ]/u'     =>   'I',
        '/[íìîï]/u'     =>   'i',
        '/[éèêë]/u'     =>   'e',
        '/[ÉÈÊË]/u'     =>   'E',
        '/[óòôõºö]/u'   =>   'o',
        '/[ÓÒÔÕÖ]/u'    =>   'O',
        '/[úùûü]/u'     =>   'u',
        '/[ÚÙÛÜ]/u'     =>   'U',
        '/ç/'           =>   'c',
        '/Ç/'           =>   'C',
        '/ñ/'           =>   'n',
        '/Ñ/'           =>   'N',
        '/–/'           =>   '-', // UTF-8 hyphen to "normal" hyphen
        '/[’‘‹›‚]/u'    =>   ' ', // Literally a single quote
        '/[“”«»„]/u'    =>   ' ', // Double quote
        '/ /'           =>   ' ', // nonbreaking space (equiv. to 0x160)
    );
```

Thx :)

I have found that here : [Remove all special characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string)

Comment: Instead of writing and accepting whatever, you should take the time to find a real solution. Keep in mind that your question and the accepted answer have for vocation to help eventual future users.