# Zend mcrypt-aes without special characters in the encrypted text

Tags: php, encryption, zend-framework

I am using the zend mcrypt function for the encryption of a text.

The encryption is done using the code below,

```
use Zend\Crypt\BlockCipher;
use Zend\Crypt\Symmetric\Mcrypt;

$blockCipher = new BlockCipher(new Mcrypt(array('algo' => 'aes'));
$blockCipher->setKey('enCryKey');
$result = $blockCipher->encrypt('this is a secret message');
echo "Encrypted text: $result \n";
```

There are some special characters appearing in the encrypted text. But, i have to use this in a URL and i don't want any special characters in the URL, because of url encoding difference for different mails.

Is there any way to avoid the special characters from the encrypted text which uses zend mcrypt(aes) for encryption?

Comment: When you say "don't want any special characters in the URL", is this actually going to be part of a URL? If it is, why not use `urlencode()`?. The security implications of what you may be suggesting are a different matter altogether, however...

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) i am using this encrypted text in a URL for some authentication. Some  of the mail like `zoho` decode the URL twice so  special chars like `+` in the text is converted to `%252B`, where other mails encode it into `%2B` so this difference in the URL make it hard to process. That's why i wanted to avoid the special characters.

Comment: Can you not hex encode it?

Comment: @LukePark But how? can you please explain?

Comment: use preg_replace (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string)

Comment: @rubin I cant just replace the all the special characters with null, because i have to decrypt the string. With out the full string we cant decrypt the string currectly right?

Comment: ohh sure @kuttoozz try this.. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php)

Comment: @rubin i think a little more clarification. suppose i have a text `hi..hello` and i have encrypted it into `XfHd3$%fd` and using `preg_match` i have converted the string into `XfHd3fd`. Then is it really possible to decrypt `XfHd3fd` to `hi..hello`.

Comment: yes sure, you decrypt the `$string` you get your actual text.. thanks.

Comment: I tried it but it was not working @rubin