# Replace and Remove character at the same time using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove all the illegal character and replace the space with underscore so i use this code:

```
function sanitize_file_name($filename) {
    $filename = preg_replace("/([^A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]|[\.]{2})/", "", $filename);
    return basename($filename);
}
```

for example i have a filename like **"www..//../no way"** when i sanitize it, it become **'wwwno_way'**.

it work to remove the other character that i want but the problem is i don't know how to replace the space with underscore at the same time using preg_replace. Is it posible? and how i can accomplish it?

Comment: please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string

Comment: Use preg_replace_callback(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: @Tegito123 thanks, i know how to replace using 2 regex but is it possible just using 1 regular expression to accomplish it?

Comment: `$filename = str_replace(' ', '_', preg_replace('/[^\w.]|\.{2}/', '', $filename));`

Comment: No that is not possible, unless you use a callback but that will be slower than using a separate, plain (non-regex) replace just for those spaces.

Comment: `A-Za-z0-9_` is `\w`.

Comment: ah ok i guess i have to use two regex. thanks. @anubhava it still not work.

Comment: First thing, apply `basename` **before** the replacement.

Comment: You don't need a regex to replace spaces, `str_replace` will do it. `str_replace(' ', '_', $string)`

Comment: @user3783243 well i need regex to replace other character not just space.

Comment: Yes, but you said you'll need 2 regexs, you actually only need 1. Replace the characters, then replace the spaces.

Comment: yep i think i will use the string replace for the other one. seem like there is no way i can get just by one regex. silly me.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte ah sorry i missed but in my real code it already removed.

Answer (score 0):

In preg_replace() function the second param is the param you want to get replaced with.

```
function sanitize_file_name($filename) {
$filename = preg_replace("/([^A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]|[\.]{2})/", "_", $filename);
return basename($filename);
}
```

Comment: it make $text = 'www..//../no way'; into www_____no_way. which it suppose just www_no_way.

Comment: it is because the preg_replace is replacing every illegal character with the "_", if you want only spaces to be replaced with "_" then you'll have to use the str_replace in the final return statement after preg_replace.

Comment: yes that is why i'm asking is it posible to use single regex to remove space and replace other character with ''.