# How to remove special characters from file name after upload

Tags: php, laravel-5, preg-replace

I am uploading a zip folder using Laravel after uploading I am extracting this zip folder using the ***zip archive*** everything works perfectly but I have a problem with file names in this folder, The extracted folder may contain many files these file names have special characters like " æ Æ Ø " which I want to remove from the file names.

I have used preg_replace but failed to rename the file.

```
preg_replace('/[ÆØæøÅå]/', '',path/K01_H3_N01 - Længdesnit A-A.pdf);
```

I only want to remove " æ Æ Ø " these characters from the file name. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you catch the return value and renamed the file with Storage::move(...)?

Comment: bro all problem is that after uploading I am extracting the zip folder and files is there

Answer (score 1):

You can use Storage to save the files to the disk you prefer (S3, local, ...)
with `Storage::put('file.jpg', $uploaded_file);` you can simply store it with a new filename.

UPDATE:
As seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string) SO Answer, you can do the following:

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.

   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
echo clean('a|"bc!@£de^&$f g');
```

Comment: we need the original name also that's why I need to remove the special characters

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `glob` function to get list path for all path which where extracted and loop that that list and rename each file by replacing all special char

```
$filesPaths = glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/[ÆØæøÅå]/'); 
// This will return an array with old all list of files which pathname matches the given patern
```

after that you can loop and rename files

```
foreach($filesPaths as $path){

    // Get the last part of the path which is the name of the file
    $old_name = basename($path); 

     // replace old special char by empty string
    $new_path= preg_replace('/[ÆØæøÅå]/', '', $path);

    // Generate a path by replacing the old file name in the path
    rename($path, str_replace($old_name, basename($newPath), $new_path);
}
```