# preg_replace vs trim PHP

Tags: php

I am working with a slug function and I dont fully understand some of it and was looking for some help on explaining.

My first question is about this line in my slug function `$string = preg_replace('# +#', '-', $string);` Now I understand that this replaces all spaces with a '-'. What I don't understand is what the + sign is in there for which comes after the white space in between the #.

Which leads to my next problem. I want a trim function that will get rid of spaces but only the spaces after they enter the value. For example someone accidentally entered "Arizona  " with two spaces after the a and it destroyed the pages linked to Arizona.

So after all my rambling I basically want to figure out how I can use a trim to get rid of accidental spaces but still have the preg_replace insert '-' in between words.

ex.. "Sun City West  " = "sun-city-west"

This is my full slug function-

```
function getSlug($string){
if(isset($string) && $string <> ""){
    $string = strtolower($string);
    //var_dump($string); echo "<br>";
    $string = preg_replace('#[^\w ]+#', '', $string);
    //var_dump($string); echo "<br>";
    $string = preg_replace('# +#', '-', $string);
}
return $string;
```

}

Comment: Topically relevant: [PHP function to make slug (URL string)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2955251/2943403) and [Convert string into slug with single-hyphen delimiters only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3022185/2943403)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function getSlug($string) {
  return preg_replace('#\s+#', '-', trim($string));
}
```

It first trims extra spaces at the beginning and end of the string, and then replaces all the other with the `-` character.

Here your regex is:

```
#\s+#
```

which is:

```
#  = regex delimiter
\s = any space character
+  = match the previous character or group one or more times
#  = regex delimiter again
```

so the regex here means: "match any sequence of one or more whitespace character"

Answer (score 2):

The `+` means *at least one of the preceding character*, so it matches one or more spaces.  The `#` signs are one of the ways of marking the start and end of a regular expression's pattern block.

For a trim function, PHP handily provides `trim()` which removes all leading and trailing whitespace.