# How to remove any special character from php array?

Tags: php, arrays

How to remove any special character from php array?

I have array like:

```
$temp = array (".com",".in",".au",".cz");
```

I want result as:

```
$temp = array ("com","in","au","cz");
```

I got result by this way:

```
$temp = explode(",",str_replace(".","",implode(",",$temp)));
```

But is there any php array function with we can directly remove any character from all values of array? I tried and found only spaces can be removed with `trim()` but not for any character.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022185/regular-expression-sanitize-php

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [**preg_replace function**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). This will replace anything that isn't a letter, number or space.

[**SEE DEMO**](https://eval.in/184370)

```
<?php
$temp = array (".com",".in",".aus",".cz");
$temp = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/", "", $temp );
print_r($temp);

//outputs
Array
(
    [0] =>  com
    [1] =>  in
    [2] =>  aus
    [3] =>  cz
)

?>
```

Comment: Replace with an empty string, not with a space

Comment: yea exactly... empty string should be pass in function otherwise it returns as " com".

Comment: @swap7927 You're welcome. I was happy to do it. I know you'll do the same for someone else

Answer (score 5):

I generaly make a function

```
function make_slug($data)
     {
         $data_slug = trim($data," ");
         $search = array('/','\\',':',';','!','@','#','$','%','^','*','(',')','_','+','=','|','{','}','[',']','"',"'",'<','>',',','?','~','`','&',' ','.');
         $data_slug = str_replace($search, "", $data_slug);
         return $data_slug;
     }
```

And then call it in this way

```
$temp = array (".com",".in",".au",".cz");


for($i = 0; $i<count($temp); $i++)
{
    $temp[$i] = make_slug($temp[$i]);
}

print_r($temp);
```

Each value of $temp will then become free of special characters

See the [Demo](https://eval.in/184385)

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem please execute the following code snippet

```
    $temp = array (".com",".in",".au",".cz");
    function strip_special_chars($v)
    {
        return str_replace('.','',$v);
    }
    $result[]=array_map('strip_special_chars',$temp);
```

Comment: check ur code before posting ans. it does not work.str_replace works for string only not php array.

Answer (score 0):

Actually [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) can trim any character(s) you wish if you provide the 2nd argument (character mask). As it's name implies, this will only remove characters from the beginning and end of the string. In your case [`ltrim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) may be more appropriate.

You can use `array_map()` and `ltrim()` together with a third parameter for the character mask like this:

```
$temp = array_map('ltrim', $temp, array_fill(0, count($temp), '.'));
```

The third parameter should be an array of arguments matching the length of the array you're processing, which is why I used `array_fill()` to create it.