# How to remove special symbol from string in the php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have to remove `:` from the string colon
for example `$chapter=Area of shape:triangle`

I have already tried `preg_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]',$chapter);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression Sanitize (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022185/regular-expression-sanitize-php)

Comment: i have to remove that colon from the string

Comment: WTF does this have to do with what the `facebook` tag stands for? Please tag appropriately, not randomly.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot delimiters and the second parameter of preg_replace function.

```
preg_replace('~[^a-zA-Z0-9]+~', '', $chapter);
```

Comment: you don't need to have + after the negated char class.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand the question or I over-simplify it, but ain't it just:

```
str_replace(":", "", $chapter);
```

?
This would return $chapter with all colons removed.