# how to remove speacial character like: & ) ( \ / from the string using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

How to remove/escape special charater fro the script

String's are

```
echo $position="marketing & executive cum \ stock ";

Outputs are: marketing & executive cum \ stock
```

But I want result after removing:

```
output: marketing executive cum stock
```

how it is posible ?

is there any solutions please help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression Sanitize (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022185/regular-expression-sanitize-php)

Answer (score 1):

By using preg_replace() you can do this

```
function cleanString($string) {
   $string = str_replace(array( '(', ')' ), '', $string);
   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', $string); 
}

echo cleanString('marketing & executive cum \ stock ');
```

Comment: thanks its works but i want to remove )( these also so please suggest..

Comment: @Muthu17 : this would be great : https://eval.in/752861 to get single space

Comment: @Niklesh Good one. It will help

Answer (score 1):

Use Following

```
$position="marketing & executive cum \ stock ";

echo preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\(\) ]/', '', $position);
```

Comment: its working but a want to remove )( also so how it is posible

Comment: preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $position);

Answer (score 0):

This question is a possible duplicate of this
[Remove all special characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string)
So please remove this question