# Removing wildcards from the string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In my address i have the following wildcard characters:
`!@#$%^&*()_+./\;' "`

I want to replace the above the wildcards from the address with nothing using preg_replace.

So if i have an address like this.

> Street # 453, XYZ - Road. / City, State.

it should be replaced with

> Street453RoadCityState

What is the proper regular expression pattern for this?

Comment: Research `character classes`, https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html. This is a very easy task with regex. (it takes 4 characters, including delimiters for the `preg_replace`)

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022185/regular-expression-sanitize-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$text = "Street # 453, XYZ - Road. / City, State.";
$text = preg_replace('[\W+]', '', $text);
echo($text);
```

Update:

You can simply use `\W+` (same as `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`) or just use `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` if you don't want the underscores as well.

`'^'` character represents `'NOT'` in regex. So anything that is not what comes after `'^'` will be replaced.

You can use this website to check your regex patterns:
https://regexr.com/

Comment: The answer is still wrong, remember that `[\W+]` is still not the same as `\W+` - although my old comment had been deleted for no reasons. You are putting the wanted quantifier inside the character class which means that the regex engine looks for "not a word character or a plus sign" which is essentially redundant. This  step repeats at every character. Plus you copied the solution.

Comment: `\W` does not match the underscore as requested in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
preg_replace('/[!@#$%^&*()_+.\/\\\\;\' "]/', '', $text)
```

Note `\` must be written as `\\\\` and `/` must be written as `\/`.

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/oEWcn1/1).

Answer (score 0):

You might simply be looking for

```
\W+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rNSFpH/1).
You did eliminate `XYZ` in your example as well but this might not be intended.