# Why Inflector::slug in Yii2 generates wrong latin string from cyrillic?

Tags: php, yii2, slug

`Inflector::slug` in `Yii2` generates not correct string from cyrillic.

Example: `автоматизация` -> `avtomatizacia`, but it must be `avtomatizaciya`; `зачислить` -> `zacislit`, but it must be `zachislit`. How to fix it?

I use this for SEO urls. Can this influence if search engines will not recognise the correct keyword to improve SEO results for my website?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because it uses ISO 9 for handling  [cyrillic](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general#TOC-Cyrillic) and aparently its [ISO 9:1995](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9#ISO/R_9) version.
Now when I put:

```
echo \yii\helpers\Inflector::transliterate('автоматизация', 'Cyrillic;  Any-Latin');
echo yii\helpers\Inflector::transliterate('зачислить', $a);
```

I get:

```
avtomatizaciâ 
začislitʹ
```

Which is as in ISO 9:1995. Slug method does conversion to ASCII character to charcter and so for example č gets changed into c.

You can still do as you want just [str-replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) where needed.
Or you can do the transliteration another way [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461406/cyrillic-transliteration-in-php).