# PHP Cyrillic transliteration: full html content (without damaging html tags)?

Tags: php, regex, transliteration

How can i easily translite full html content cyrillic  to latency without damaging html tags. eg:

```
<title>Главная страница</title>
```

to:

```
<title>Glavnaja stranica</title>
```

**Example:**

```
 $cyr="<p>Кирилица</p>";
    $lat="<p>Look that p tag replaced with п</p>";
    $cyrArray = [
        'а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п',
        'р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я',
        'А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П',
        'Р','С','Т','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я'
    ];
    $latArray = [
        'a','b','v','g','d','e','io','zh','z','i','y','k','l','m','n','o','p',
        'r','s','t','u','f','h','ts','ch','sh','sht','a','i','y','e','yu','ya',
        'A','B','V','G','D','E','Io','Zh','Z','I','Y','K','L','M','N','O','P',
        'R','S','T','U','F','H','Ts','Ch','Sh','Sht','A','I','Y','e','Yu','Ya'
    ];
    $cyr = str_replace($cyrArray, $latArray, $cyr);
    $lat = str_replace($latArray, $cyrArray, $lat);
    echo cyr;// it's ok! no problem.
    echo "<br/>";
    echo  $lat;//but in lat to cryillic we should skip html tags
```

> Before i asking a question, i was carefully search google and stackoverflow and didn't find capable solution.

Comment: You could just let Google do it for you: [Google Translate My Page](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/) and [Adding Google Translate to a web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243818/adding-google-translate-to-a-web-site)

Comment: Yeah i know, but it need to me in our CMS features. I mean this should be server hosted php script and it is worked when user added new page to site in cyrillic, must transliteration to latin and saved to database also

Comment: Also server works in local area and not always online

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cyrillic transliteration in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461406/cyrillic-transliteration-in-php)

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov: indeed the linked answer may help you. However, I suggest to try Ilyich answer first, and if it doesn't fit your requirements to test the accepted answer in a second time (or better, build an associative array and use `strtr` in place of `str_replace`).

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov: more informations about [ICU transforms](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general).

Comment: Ok i did before 1. Possible duplicate of Cyrillic transliteration in PHP and assoc arrays but what about skip tags when you transliting latin->cryllic?

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov: In this case you have to use a different way: Use DOMDocument to build a DOM tree and transliterate each text node (use XPath to find them). This way, html tags are not affected.

Comment: Yes i have test this to but when html content contains  numerous of line it takes much time as accepted

Comment: I used http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ for that

Comment: Try with DOMDocument instead.

Comment: Ok i will try and post results also.

Comment: @Casimir what do you think about using dictionary for tags. I mean first replace tag with alias and after replacing letter back them using str_replace.

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov: not a good idea: unable to handle html attributes, nor style or script content, unable to deal with comments or DTD.

Comment: Yeah bad idea. Anyway but Domdocument also slow . Maybe i will tomorrow end this task and post results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Converts SR-Latin to SR-Cyr
 *
 * @param  String  $word
 * @return String  $word
 */
public static function filterWord($word)
{
    $lat = [
        'a','b','v','g','d','đ','e','ž','z','i','j','k','l','lj','m','n','nj','o','p','r','s','t','ć','u','f','h','c','č','dž','š','&scaron;',
        'A','B','V','G','D','Đ','E','Ž','Z','I','J','K','L','Lj','M','N','Nj','O','P','R','S','T','Ć','U','F','H','C','Č','Dž','Š','&Scaron;'
    ];

    $cyr = [
        'а','б','в','г','д','ђ','е','ж','з','и','ј','к','л','љ','м','н','њ','о','п','р','с','т','ћ','у','ф','х','ц','ч','џ','ш','ш',
        'А','Б','В','Г','Д','Ђ','Е','Ж','З','И','Ј','К','Л','Љ','М','Н','Њ','О','П','Р','С','Т','Ћ','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Џ','Ш','Ш'
    ];

    $spec1 = [
        'Нј','нј','Лј','лј','ДЖ','Дж','дж'
    ];
    $spec2 = [
        'Њ','њ','Љ','љ','Џ','Џ','џ'
    ];

    $tags_cyr = [
        '<х1','</х1>','<х2','</х2>','<х3','</х3>','<х4','</х4>','<х5','</х5>','<х6','</х6>','<п','</п>','<спан','</спан>','<б','</б>','<стронг','</стронг>','<смалл','</смалл>','<и','</и>','<у','</у>','<имг','</имг>','<див','</див>','<а','</а>','<суб','</суб>','<суп','</суп>','<бр>','<бр/>','<bр','<хр/>','&нбсп;','&лт;','&гт;','&ндасх;','&мдасх;','хреф','срц','&лдqуо;','&бдqуо;','&лсqуо;','&рсqуо;','&сцарон;','&Сцарон;','&тилде;'
    ];

    $tags_lat = [
        '<h1','</h1>','<h2','</h2>','<h3','</h3>','<h4','</h4>','<h5','</h5>','<h6','</h6>','<p','</p>','<span','</span>','<b','</b>','<strong','</strong>','<small','</small>','<i','</i>','<u','</u>','<img','</img>','<div','</div>','<a','</a>','<sub','</sub>','<sup','</sup>','<br>','<br/>','<br','<hr/>','&nbsp;','&lt;','&gt;','&ndash;','&mdash;','href','src','&ldquo;','&bdquo;','&lsquo;','&rsquo;','ш','Ш','&tilde;'
    ];

    $word = str_replace($tags_cyr, $tags_lat, str_replace($spec1, $spec2, str_replace($lat, $cyr, $word)));

    $lastPos = 0;
    $positions = [];

    while (($lastPos = mb_strpos($word, '<', $lastPos, 'UTF-8')) !== false) {
        $positions[] = $lastPos;
        $lastPos = $lastPos + mb_strlen('<', 'UTF-8');
    }

    foreach ($positions as $position) {
        if(mb_strpos($word, '>', 0, 'UTF-8') !== false) {
            $end   = mb_strpos($word, ">", $position, 'UTF-8') - $position;
            $tag  = mb_substr($word, $position, $end, 'UTF-8');
            $tag_lat = str_replace($cyr, $lat, $tag);
            $word = str_replace($tag, $tag_lat, $word);
        }
    }

    return $word;
}
```