# How to convert fake characters to real one in PHP?

Tags: php, character-encoding, char, decode, iconv

character `B` can have

HEX code = `0x42` (real letter) or `0x412` (fake letter)

DEC code = `66` (real letter) or `1042` (fake letter)

HTML with named char ref = `B` (real letter) or `&#x412;` (fake letter)

Java string = `B` (real letter) or `\u0412B` (fake letter)

When I parse content from remote URL with CURL I see on macOS in both variants letter `B`. But really it could be not real letter `B`. I check it with [this online tool](http://www.mauvecloud.net/charsets/CharCodeFinder.html) is letter real or not.

This code helps me for one letter:

```
$content = str_replace("В", "B", $content);
```

But how can I make the same with PHP for all other illegal characters?

Comment: Are "illegal/fake" characters any outside of ASCII?

Comment: That's not a "fake" character. It's a cyrillic one and is pronounced as "V", but happens to look exactly like the latin B character. You can't magically convert these ... if you want only latin letters, then you might want to restrict your character set to ASCII (or a similar one that doesn't include all alphabets on the planet).

Comment: @user3783243 Yes, I think fake chars is outside of ASCII. But is there any command that can translit it. When I search in Excel file for product SKU code "B250C" it's can't be found due to incorrect first charecter B. If I retype from keyboard "B250C" it founds line in Excel.

Comment: @Narf Wow, yes you are right! I forgot that russian language has the same letter)

Comment: Are all the characters you want to convert known? An uppercase greek beta has the same issue. A `B` is not the same as a beta, they have very different meanings in science.

Comment: @user3783243 yes they're known, here is the same letters in cyrillyc and latin: Е, Н, У, Х, В, А, О, С, М, Т

Comment: Put them in an array and use `str_replace`.

Comment: @user3783243 you or Narf could answer the question and I will accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cyrillic transliteration in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461406/cyrillic-transliteration-in-php)

Comment: You are talking about Unicode confusables. https://www.unicode.org/Public/security/latest/confusables.txt But why do you say that characters are "illegal?"

Comment: @TomBlodget I wrote it for a better understanding of the question. You are right it's correct char in utf8 (out of ASCII) that could be confusable.

Comment: You forgot Р and К; also, depending on the font used, the lowercase versions of Н and И can be confused for lowercase versions of N and U respectively, and З (pronounced like a "Z") looks a lot like the number 3. Plus, I think Greek had a character that looked exactly like a semicolon, and there surely are many more - again, you can't rely on a blacklist. Transliteration, on the other hand, would convert В to V, Х to H, etc. Sorry about not writing this as an answer ... I don't feel like writing it out properly right now; up for grabs.

Comment: @Narf I agree with you. Also I forgot about Ukrainian character "і" which uppercase the same as "I".