# PHP preg_replace() - Memory Issues. Alternative?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, slug

In a site I'm working on, im converting strings to slugs using the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955251/php-function-to-make-slug-url-string).  It works, but I'm finding there are HUGE memory leak issues.  I've done some research and found that this is just currently a bug in PHP.

Are there any alternatives to accomplish something like strings to slug?

EDIT:

There's another interesting angle to this problem.  I'm re-developing a scraper that was made using `regex` (ugh, i know), so I decided to use DOMDocument / XPath as a solution.

The interesting thing is, the original `regex` scrape, also uses the above slugify() function, and there are no memory issues.  However, once I setup the DOMDocument scrape, the scrape crashes halfway through and the error is always on the `preg_replace()` line in the `slugify()` function above.

So despite both scenarios using the exact same slugify() function, only the DOMDocument version crashes on the `preg_replace()` line

Answer (score 3):

Preg_replace is pretty good for this, but an alternative is to hack them out using http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: right.  Any pointers to a slugify() function that utilizes this?

Comment: ha yeah i know... but I'm doing a scrape (NOT using preg_replace!  Use DOM Document) but when a certain text comes in, I have to make it into a slug before going into the DB.  So I end up with these loops of preg_replace() and apparently it's just compounding the memory usage each time

Comment: UGH! man I don't know. I still don't have a strong solution for you :/ Have you tried separating your preg_replace out to a function to see if you can kill it? Maybe try some phpUnit on it... I'm sorry man :(

Comment: Hm, i haven't tried putting the preg_replace() in a separate function.  What do you mean by "kill it"?  Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

By unsetting the variable, you should be able to free up some memory. Yes it's dirty but might work

```
static public function slugify($text) {    
  // replace non letter or digits by -   
  $text2 = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);

  // unset $text to free up space
  unset($text);
  // trim   
  $text2 = trim($text2, '-');

  // transliterate   
  $text2 = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text2);

  // lowercase
  $text2 = strtolower($text2);

  // remove unwanted characters
  $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text2);

  // unset $text2 to free up space
  unset($text2);

  if (empty($text))   {
    return 'n-a';   
  }
  return $text; 
}
```

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=35258&edit=1

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#84285

Hopefully you find a cleaner solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 0):

I found this bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38728 and it says to use the `mb_eregi_replace()` function insead.

It worked for me.