# preg_replace: trying to understand to make title as a slug for url

Tags: php, preg-replace

Hi first time dealing with preg_replace and found damn complex to understand specially learner.

Trying to change title string to slug for url structure where it remove all special character like `( ) ? *` and replace multiple space into single `-` with converting all text in to lower case.

Here is my funny code but not getting desire output.

```
$title_slug = $q_slug->title;
$title_slug = preg_replace("/[\s+\?]/", " ", $title_slug);        
$title_slug = str_replace("  ", " ", $title_slug);
$title_slug = str_replace(" ", "-", $title_slug);
$title_slug = preg_replace("/[^\w^\_]/"," ",$title_slug);
$title_slug = preg_replace("/\s+/", "-", $title_slug);
$title_slug = strtolower($title_slug);

return $title_slug;
```

EDIT: Added Example

Example: `if my title is what is * the() wonder_ful not good?? and where???`
Result: `if-my-title-is-what-is-the-wonder_ful-not-good-and-where`

Feel free to laugh :) and million thanks for help.

Comment: It is possible to do this with 2-3 lines. Can you specify what your desired output is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = strtolower($string);
$string = preg_replace("/\W+/", "-", $string); // \W = any "non-word" character
$string = trim($string, "-");
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this tutorial](http://cubiq.org/the-perfect-php-clean-url-generator) for a clean URL generator, or even use [this existing SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2955878/427992) which eschews regular expressions altogether. This will probably get the job done:

```
function toAscii($str) {
   $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
   $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_| -]/", '', $clean);
   $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
   return preg_replace("/[\/_| -]+/", '-', $clean);
}
```

Comment: I was already on Google to search for this type of answer! iconv() is a great helper for this kind of tasks!

Comment: @powtac its really happy to being on stackoverflow. people are amazing and having great experience and expertise and always ready to help.

Comment: Your answer is good one only one thing, it's removing `_` which I want. However now I am really confuse which answer is the best to choose all are working fine but Salman A answer is perfect what I need

Answer (score 2):

Here's [a nice function](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/59486-php-create-seo-friendly-url-titles-slugs/#axzz2JCfcCHFX) to do just that:

```
function toSlug ($string) {
        $string = strtolower($string);
        // Strip any unwanted characters
        $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $string);
        // Clean multiple dashes or whitespaces
        $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
        // Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
        $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);

        return $string;
}
```