# Creating dynamic auto-incrementing seo friendly url's from php and sql

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, seo

Clicking on user John Smith in position    **user_id** 1 It should go to the url www.example.com/John-Smith as opposed to profile.php?uid=1

When you click on user John Smith in **user_id** 2 It should go to the url www.example.com/John-Smith-2
profile.php?uid=2

When you click on user Kia Dull in **user_id** 3 It should go to the url www.example.com/Kia-Dull
profile.php?uid=3

```
Table Users

User_id    First_name    last_name
   1          John         Smith
   2          John         Smith
   3          Kia          Dull
```

How do I format my .Htaccess file and php/sql for this.

When a user profile is clicked I just simply lead it here.

```
<a href="<?php echo $row[first_name] ?>-<?php echo $row[last_name] ?>"
```

which doesn't do anything.

and here's my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?uid=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at following article. Hope it describes clear/simple and with example what you need.


#### SEO Friendly URLs with PHP

Answer (score 1):

I would create another column in the database called something like "slug" and make it a unique string. Now, when adding a new record, I'd generate the slug for this one.

I found an example for a function to create the slug as an answer to this question: [PHP function to make slug (URL string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955251/php-function-to-make-slug-url-string#answers)

The slugify-function, provided in the answer to the quoted question, does not check if the value already exists in your database. You'd have to do it yourself and add a suffix like "-1" if the slug already exists.

If you have done all that, your data should look similar to this:

```
Table Users

User_id    First_name    Last_name     Slug
   1          John         Smith     john-smith
   2          John         Smith    john-smith-1
   3          Kia          Dull       kia-dull
```

The next steps should be quite easy.

This would be an option to create the links:

```
<a href="<?php echo $row['Slug'] ?>"><?php echo $row['First_name'] ?> <?php echo $row['Last_name'] ?></a>
```

The .htaccess file should be fine like you have it already ...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?uid=$1 [L]
```

And you just have to query the table for a value like $_GET['uid'] in your *profile.php* file. Now I'd rename the parameter *uid* into *slug*, because it's not longer an ID, but you can get the ID quite easily by querying after the slug.

Benefits of this solution:

- Easy to debug. The slug is something you can find 1:1 in the database. If you now have a URL you can tell, without guessing, which user it is.
- Consistent. Even if you'd delete the row with id=1, the row id=2 would still have the slug "john-smith-1"

**FYI:**

> A slug is the part of a URL which identifies a page using human-readable keywords.
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL#Slug

Answer (score 0):

You Missed Little bit of code the exact Code is like this...

```
<a href="<?php echo $row['first_name']."-".$row['last_name']."-".$row['User_id']."profile.php?uid=".$row['User_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['first_name']."-".$row['last_name']."-".$row['User_id']; ?></a>
```

this creat the URL which you want and do changes in HTACCESS as per the URL if required.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the "echo" to display the data in that links,

```
<a href="<?php **echo** $row[first_name] ?>-<?php **echo** $row[last_name] ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your htaccess rules. The rule basically matches anything that ends with `-` followed by numbers

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule -([\d]+)$ profile.php?uid=$1 [L]
```

And something like this for your link.

```
<a href="<?=$row['first_name']?>-<?=$row['last_name']?>-<?=$row['user_id']?>">User</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^.*]+)$ profile.php?uid=$1
```

Should do the trick