# move_uploaded_file when file has a slash in the name?

Tags: php, image, upload

I'm using a function which generates a random encryption for image file names.

Sometimes the file name will have a / in the name. In these cases move_uploaded_file breaks and the image is not uploaded.

How can take the / into account when saving the file without having to change my method of encryption?

Comment: Is "/" accepted by any file system in a file name???

Comment: I think your problem is the filesystem rejecting the slash.

Comment: When I upload an image with a slash manually it works.

Comment: encryption or hashing for the file name you create?  Use a method that doesn't generate illegal filename characters - or use `str_replace` to replace the illegal characters with `_` or something similar.

Comment: because "/" indicates a directory separator. instead of "/" try using "-"

Comment: @PhilipK are you using a Mac by any chance?

Comment: Mac's Finder app displays "/" but under the hood the file name contains a ":" instead (if you look at it in the terminal).

Comment: "/" is definitely not legal for a file name because it is a directory separator.

Comment: While in this case it is generated on php side. @jon problem with replacing a / with -. how to I determine if a - was germinated as a / or - when decrypting?

Comment: What does this mean "generated on PHP side" ? Try to look at the file with the Terminal, you'll see if it is a ":" or a "/".

Comment: Encrypted output should not be used as a file name as it will end up causing a lot more issues than that (depending on which encryption algorithm you use).  But if you insist on doing that, you can use the [`base64_encode`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and [`base64_decode`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) methods and strip the `=` signs off the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"/" is not legal in a file name, because it is the directory separator.
You can use a slugify function to purge the string, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955251/php-function-to-make-slug-url-string) for instance.

But I wouldn't recommend that. You should find another way to name your files, for instance by using a md5 or sha1 hash of them.