# Magento: show custom attribute in body class

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a custom category attribute that i want to add to the body class. As far as I could find out what people do is

1. Override the CategoryController and add something like `$root->addBodyClass($category->getMyAttribute());` But I don't want to override core classes...
2. In the admin panel they add something like `<reference name=”root”><action method=”addBodyClass”><className>caravan-motorhome-lighting</className></action></reference>` to each and every category not using the attribute itself but adding the class directly. As I already have an attribute, I surely don't want do clone it and add the class this way.

So what my favourite solution would be is some layout update I can add to the local.xml that says

```
<reference name=”root”>
    <action method=”addBodyClass”>
        <className>
            get value of my custom attribute here dynamically
        </className>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Does anyone have an idea how this could work or another idea that I didn't even think of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a really cool feature of Magento layout XML to achieve this. You'll need a module to achieve it. Either create a module specifically for this or use a theme module if you have one — this is up to you to decide what you think is best.

I'll show you an example where I'll add a class containing the ID of the category to the body tag:

In my layout XML, I'm going to add via the `catalog_category_default` handle. This way, I can use `Mage::registry('current_category')` later to retrieve the current category. So, in your layout XML do something similar to this:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="addBodyClass">
            <className helper="mymodule/my_helper/getCategoryClass" />
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

This attribute is the important part: `helper="mymodule/my_helper/getCategoryClass"`. This is equivalent to calling `Mage::helper('mymodule/my_helper')->getCategoryClass();` in code.

Whatever is returned from that function will be used as the value for the `<className>` node. You may want to use a different helper that you deem more appropriate, this is up to you to decide.

Carrying on the with the example, here's the function:

```
public function getCategoryClass() {
    return 'category-id-' . Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
}
```

You'll want to change the code so that it retrieves the value of your attribute. e.g `getMyAttribute()` on the category returned by `Mage::registry('current_category')`.

Also, you'll  need to ensure that the return is something that is suitable as a CSS class. In this example we don't need to do anything as the ID will always be just number which will be appended to `category-id-`. If the value of your attribute is not always going to be safe you might want to consider using something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2955878/733347)

[image: It works!]

Comment: This sounds amazing - exactly what I was looking for. I gonna try it out!

Comment: @RiaElliger Excellent, glad to hear it.

Comment: Already used the same feature to add themed CSS based on the same attribute. This is truly amazing :)