# Where can I find a list of IDs or rules for the PHP transliterator (Intl)?

Tags: php, transliteration, intl

[`Transliterator::listIDs()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/transliterator.listids.php) will list IDs, but apparently it's not a complete list.

In the [example from this page](http://php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php), the ID looks like:

```
Any-Latin; NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC; [:Punctuation:] Remove; Lower();
```

which is kind of weird, because IDs are supposed to be unique. This looks more like a rule, but it doesn't work if I pass it to the `createFromRules` method :)

Anyway, I'm trying to remove any punctuation from the string, except dash (`-`), or characters from a specific list.

Do you know if that's possible? Or is there some documentation that better explains the syntax for the transliterator ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ids that [`Transliterator::listIDs()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/transliterator.listids.php) are the "basic ids". The example you gave is a "compound id". You can see the [ICU docs on this](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general).

You can also create your own rules with [`Transliterator::createFromRules()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/transliterator.createfromrules.php).

You can take a look at the prefefined rules:

```
<?php
$a = new ResourceBundle(NULL, sprintf('icudt%dl-translit', INTL_ICU_VERSION), true);

foreach ($a['RuleBasedTransliteratorIDs'] as $name => $v) {
    $file = @$v['file'];
    if (!$file) {
        $file = $v['internal'];
        echo $name, " (direction $file[direction]; internal)\n";
    } else { 
        echo $name, " (direction: $file[direction])\n";
        echo $file['resource'];
    }
    echo "\n--------------\n";
}
```

After formatting, the result looks like [this](http://nebm.ist.utl.pt/~glopes/misc/rules.txt).

Comment: friendly reminder: that's a pretty intense .txt file for machine low on memory, chrome and sublime text may stop responding handling it...

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone wants a working example. The example mentioned (from the php manual) uses procedural style. To make it work with an object oriented style, use `create()` instead of `createFromRules()`

```
removePunctuation($string) {
    $transliterator = Transliterator::create("Any-Latin; NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC; [:Punctuation:] Remove;", \Transliterator::FORWARD);

    return $transliterator->transliterate($string);
}
```