# Using urlencode in mysql row php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I get some data from the database then create a link from the data.

```
<a href=\"news/people/" . urldecode($row['title']) . ".html\" target=\"_self\">"
```

the output is link is `http://wwww.website.com/news/people/ask+question+stack.html`
so instead of having the plus sign in the link i will like to hve a link with hyphen
like this  `http://wwww.website.com/news/people/ask-question-stack.html`

Thanks for the help
Newbie

Comment: + is the url encoded value for a space

Comment: does this help: urldecode(str_replace("+", "-", $row['title'])) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php function to make slug (url string)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955251/php-function-to-make-slug-url-string)

Answer (score 1):

It should be URL Encoding not URL Decoding when building a link with content from a database.  if the `content in $row['title'] = "ask question stack"`, then you could replaces spaces with hyphens and then encode your string.

```
urlencode(str_replace(' ', '-', $row['title']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
urldecode(str_replace("+", "-", $row['title']))
urldecode(str_replace(" ", "-", $row['title']))
urldecode(str_replace("_", "-", $row['title']))
urldecode(str_replace(".", "-", $row['title']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
urlencode(str_ireplace(array('+', ' ', '_', '.'), '-', $row['title']));
```