# How to return string with multiple words as one

Tags: php, mysql

In my `MySQL` database I have this table which contains multiple artists. They are placed in a field called `formated_name` and returns `strings` like for example `Lady Gaga`, so far so good. What I want to achieve is that it `returns` `ladygaga` so I can use it for my `url` later on. My whole function looks like this:

```
public function artistname_get($artist_id)  
{ 
    $this->load->database();

    $sql = "SELECT formated_name FROM artists WHERE artist_id = '".$artist_id."'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->result();

    if($data) {
        $this->response($data, 200);
    } else {
        $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artist with that name!'), 404);
    }
}
```

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: you want to remove space and convert strings to lowercase, right?

Comment: you can do that using PHP.

Comment: Yes, that was originally the title of my question, but got edited!? Whats the method called? preg_replace?

Comment: strtolower(implode("", explode(" ", $data))) - but urlencode is more appropiate for you later!

Comment: To use it in a url: make it into a slug. here's how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955251/php-function-to-make-slug-url-string

Answer (score 1):

Try out this simple way.

To remove spaces in string.

By using PHP

```
$string = 'Lady Ga ga';

$value=str_replace(' ','',$string);

echo strtolower($value);
```

---

By using *MySQL*

```
$sql = "SELECT REPLACE( formated_name, " ", "" ) FROM artists WHERE artist_id = '".$artist_id."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql offers string function for this as well if you do not want to do it with php.

ToLower function:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower

Replace to replace spaces:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

But you should additionally use something for url_encode and url_decode within php. Otherwise you may experiance problems with artists like "A & B"

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
str_replace() and `strtolower()`
```

to remove space and to convert string to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

PHP version:

```
$string = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $string));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$artist_url = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $artist_formatted_name));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $string));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT LOWER(REPLACE(formated_name, ' ', '')) AS formated_name
```

You have to do is Just use mysql functions **LOWER** and **REPLACE** together to get rid of space and capital letters

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this.....

```
<?php 
$string = 'Lady Gaga';
$value=str_replace(' ','',$string);
echo strtolower($value);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put it in URL you should clear also from special characters etc.

Use this function to convert string into alias.

```
function toAlias ($string) {
    return strtolower (preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', str_replace(' ', '-', $string)));
}
```