# PHP string modifications help needed

Tags: php, string, character, symbols

i have a specific problem, i'm recreating website and i need to leave the same ads url.
Maybe someone have ideas how to make this:

> Rental: 15K Sand Separator. 11” ID Tank w/ 3-1/16” 15K flow lines. 14,750 per month

to this:

> rental-15k-sand-separator-11-id-tank-w-3-1-16-15k-flow-lines-14-750-per-month

I've tried to change all characters to - but if there are more symbols i get more than 1 dash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do double replace:

```
// Replace anything that is not letter or number to dash
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '-', $string);
// Replace more than one dash to single dash
$string = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string);
```

As i can see, you are making SEO friendly url from some product name. Try looking for [Slug function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2955878/1346234)