# url encode and mod rewrite failing to load page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a htaccess file that rewrites my url to a more friendly url

```
 #   '/'.$i.'/'.$company;
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)(/?)$ /offer.php?i=$1&company=$2 [NC,L]
```

this works fine unless in cases like below the page renders perfectly...

/14/barringtons-wedding-cars

/13/beef-and-pudding

/12/banks-printers

however when the name of the client contains say & symbol or any other symbol the url is writen like so......

/15/bella-%26-mr-tom

/17/bonton-hair-%26-beauty-salon

/37/fuego%27s-mexican-restaurant

and all of a sudden the page comes up as 404 not found.  Is there anyway around this as I cant seem to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the Rule to the below, this should fix your issue.

**RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]*)?$ /offer.php?i=$1&company=$2 [L]**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change your `.htaccess` file, but you need to use `slugs` based on the `$company` variable when writing your url.

Instead of having this kind of url:

```
http://www.example.com/15/Fathers&Sons
```

You should write:

```
http://www.example.com/15/Fathers-Sons
```

This is the way stackoverflow and most websites works.

[Have a look at the answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955251/php-function-to-make-slug-url-string), by using this code you could write `'/'.$i.'/'.slugify($company);` when writing your url in code.