# PHP: Convert English normal text to URL

Tags: php, url, urlencode

I try to covert normal English text to url path.

For example

- `this is a text!` -> `this-is-a-text`
- `this is a text&image` -> `this-is-a-text-image`
- `are you  ok?` -> `are-you-ok`

So I try convert it with this code:

```
str_replace("-", "+", urlencode(trim($text)));
```

It doesn't covert `+` to `-`

Also it seems that doesn't work good for example for '/' and '&' (for some string dosn't work.)

Is there a better way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955251/php-function-to-make-slug-url-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your examples this should work:

```
$result = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '-', $text);
```

If you want all lower-case then use `strtolower($text)` instead, then no need for the `i` modifier.

Comment: Fast typer, exactly what I was thinking, here's a 101 of it https://regex101.com/r/vU1lP6/1.

Comment: `$result = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '-', strtolower($text)), '-');` - added `+` and `strtolower`; trim

Comment: @luchaninov: Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This process usually is called 'making slug'.
You can find various prepared functions for that.
Regarding considering Unicode, the function could be more complex.

However, your question is answered here:
[PHP function to make slug (URL string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955251/php-function-to-make-slug-url-string)