# PHP to convert string to slug

Tags: php, string

What is the best way to convert a string of text to a slug? Meaning:

- alpha allowed, convert to lowercase
- numbers are allowed
- spaces should be eliminated, not converted to dash ("-")
- accented characters replaced by equivalent standard alpha
- no other characters allowed, should be stripped out

I have found plenty of code online, but it all tends to convert spaces to dashes, which I do not want to do.

I am also interested optionally in varying the conversion, wherein:

- ampersand ("&") should be replaced by the string "and"

And also a variant wherein:

- Don't bother converting accented characters to equivalent standard alpha

Comment: so `youwantyoururltolooklikethis` instead of the cleaner looking `you-want-your-url-to-look-like-this`? Also, `accented characters replaced by equivalent standard alpha` but `Don't bother converting accented characters`. Which?

Comment: Pick a solution that's close to what you want, then modify it to add your special requirements.

Comment: You could simply remove all the dashes from the result of a standard slug generator.

Comment: There are libraries like https://github.com/cocur/slugify or https://github.com/ausi/slug-generator that allow you to customize the character translations and the delimiter.

Comment: @ausi, that's brilliant. Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is a modified function that I originally found here (http://cubiq.org/the-perfect-php-clean-url-generator). you can pass `''` as the delimiter to not use `'-'`.

```
public static function createSlug($str, $delimiter = '-'){

    $slug = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', $delimiter, preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', $delimiter, preg_replace('/[&]/', 'and', preg_replace('/[\']/', '', iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str))))), $delimiter));
    return $slug;

}
```

Comment: This is not an elegant snippet.  `preg_replace()` can receive an array of finds/replacements, so nesting calls within calls unnecessarily bloats the line.  `&` and `'` don't need to be wrapped in braces -- there is no benefit to using a character class for the single symbol.

Answer (score 4):

Previous one is good solution. But unfortunately it cuts off specific letters like ć or ż. 
If you want to keep them, then:

```
public static function createSlug($str, $delimiter = '-'){

    $unwanted_array = ['ś'=>'s', 'ą' => 'a', 'ć' => 'c', 'ç' => 'c', 'ę' => 'e', 'ł' => 'l', 'ń' => 'n', 'ó' => 'o', 'ź' => 'z', 'ż' => 'z',
        'Ś'=>'s', 'Ą' => 'a', 'Ć' => 'c', 'Ç' => 'c', 'Ę' => 'e', 'Ł' => 'l', 'Ń' => 'n', 'Ó' => 'o', 'Ź' => 'z', 'Ż' => 'z']; // Polish letters for example
    $str = strtr( $str, $unwanted_array );

    $slug = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', $delimiter, preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', $delimiter, preg_replace('/[&]/', 'and', preg_replace('/[\']/', '', iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str))))), $delimiter));
    return $slug;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function createSlug($title) {

     $title = strtolower($title);

     $replacements = ['@'=> "at", '#' => "hash", '$' => "dollar", '%' => "percentage", '&' => "and", '.' => "dot", 
                '+' => "plus", '-' => "minus", '*' => "multiply", '/' => "devide", '=' => "equal to",
                '<' => "less than", '<=' => "less than or equal to", '>' => "greater than", '<=' => "greater than or equal to",
    ];

     $title = strtr($title, $replacements);
     return $urlKey = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '-', $title);
}

echo createSlug("BLUE DIAMOND ALMONDS HONEY ROASTED @ 100 which is < 154");

// output :- blue-diamond-almonds-honey-roasted-at-100-which-is-less-than-154
```

for performance test case [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53612584/14344959)

You can test above function at [onlinephp.io](https://onlinephp.io/c/57ae0)

Comment: Your function references the variable `$str`, but you don't ever use that var in your function. On top of that, you start by declaring `$url`, which references an undeclared var `$title`, to then never reference `$url` again, instead only referencing `$title`. This is cursed.

Comment: @Charbrec code fixed. now check it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function createSlug($str,$length,$delimiter = '-'){
    $slug = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', $delimiter, preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', $delimiter, preg_replace('/[&]/', 'and', preg_replace('/[\']/', '', iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str))))), $delimiter));
    $slug = substr($slug, 0, $length);
    return $slug;
} 
$myString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit neque eleifend semper, lectus faucibus velit senectus risus felis malesuada habitant. Sollicitudin malesuada mus scelerisque eros primis dictum ultricies sagittis";
print createSlug($myString,50); // here 50 = 50 character length slug generate; you can change it 100/50/25 or etc
?>
```

Output: lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur-adipiscing-lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur-adipiscing