# MySQL, PHP; Edit column value before comparing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, str-replace

Maybe the question title isn't very clear but I don't know how to describe.

I'll try to explain:

I have a MySQL query in my PHP code like this:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name FROM persons WHERE name = :name');
$statement->execute(array(':name' => "Peter-Loew"));
```

What I want to to is to edit `:name` before comparing with `"Peter-Loew"`.

I want to run a PHP code like this on `:name` before comparing with `"Peter-Loew"`:

```
<?php
function url_replace($url_replace) {
$url_replace = str_ireplace(array('Ä','Ö','Ü'), array('Ae','Oe','Ue'), $url_replace);
$url_replace = preg_replace('~[^a-zA-Z0-9]+~', '-', $url_replace);
$url_replace = trim($url_replace, '-');
$url_replace = rtrim($url_replace, '-');
return $url_replace;
}
?>
```

How can I do this? Or, does anybody know how to call this what I'm looking for?

Comment: im down voting this because you have changed the question significantly since a valid answer was given

Comment: in addition to this here is a slug generator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641973/php-to-convert-string-to-slug/40642103#40642103

Comment: Having a lot of slugs which will show the same page may affect your seo.

Comment: @u_mulder What do you mean? Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for mysql [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name FROM persons WHERE REPLACE(name, " ", "-") = :name');
$statement->execute(array(':name' => "Peter-Loew"));
```

Comment: I don't understand why you ask for replacing `-` while your real problem is obviously of a different kind?

Comment: @David . . . Your question is quite clear and this answer answers it.  If you have *another* question, then ask it as another question.  Don't modify this one.  That will just invalidate this correct answer, which might draw downvotes.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I thought there's no way to do this in SQL itself and I wanted to keep the question clear. Sorry! I edited my question.