# any way to cache routes.php file in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm trying to add dynamic routes from database in CI. but my website is really slow after adding data into my table.

anyway to performed routes.php file? or anyway to speed up my site?

**NOTE:** i have more than 60,000 record for SEO friendly url.

routes affected my response server time, its about 4 seconds.

here is my code:

```
require_once(BASEPATH . 'database/DB' . EXT);
require_once(BASEPATH . 'helpers/url_helper' . EXT);
require_once(BASEPATH . 'helpers/text_helper' . EXT);
$db = &DB();

$query = $db->query('select id,title from news');
$result = $query->result();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $string = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $row->title));
    $route["funny-news/" . $string] = "news/newsDetails/$row->id";
}
```

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:**

newsDetails Controller code:

```
public function newsDetails($id)
    {
        $hdata['active'] = "news";
        $result['news'] = $this->mytestdb->getNewsById($id);
        $this->load->view('nheader', $hdata);
        $this->load->view('newsDetails', $result);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

Comment: You should build the route string and query for that one record instead of dumping the whole db every request. If you don't find it, 404.

Comment: @ourmandave, thanks for your reply , can you explain more please?

Comment: show us your newsdetails controller

Comment: @sintakonte, i add edit part, contain that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your `routes.php` and put the following line in

```
$route['funny-news/(.*)'] = "news/newsDetails/$1";
```

And your controller should look like

```
public function newsDetails($slug)
{
    $hdata['active'] = "news";
    $result['news'] = $this->mytestdb->getNewsBySlug($slug);
    $this->load->view('nheader', $hdata);
    $this->load->view('newsDetails', $result);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

One thing - you should use an extra field in your db for your desired slug.

A function can be found here [PHP function to make slug (URL string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955251/php-function-to-make-slug-url-string).

With this method you don't need to fill the DB with unnecessary routes.

Comment: but i need my specific , route string, for each id , was your code handle that? like `$route['funny-news/a']="news/newsDetails/321";`

Comment: why do you need an id here?

Comment: only for creating special url and fetch my data from db.and i look my sitemap too , for indexing.

Comment: your sitemap should contain urls like `/funny-news/i-am-the-first-funny-news/` or something like that  there is no need for an id here - and if you need a possibility to call it with an id anyway - just make a new function..

Comment: you mean , i fetch my info from db , with name? like `i-am-the-first-funny-news`

Comment: yep exactly - by creating a new column in your database called `slug` or something like that - and creating that slug from your title with help from the linked `slugify` function

Comment: let me try that , come back as soon as i can.

Comment: i face new problem, if i need route to root directory , like `$route['(.*)'] = "news/newsDetails/$1";` and another one `$route['(.*)'] = "product/proDetails/$1";` , how can i handle it?

Comment: that won't work because how should the program know where to look and what happens if both titles are existent in products and news - which of these two would you like ? ;) in situations like this - you should always have a prefix in urls; e.g. for your products `/product/your-product` and for your news `/funny-news/i-am-the-first-funny-news/`

Comment: your answer is acceptable, one more question. any way to make routes.php Parallel ? that can run while other part running?

Comment: what do you mean with that ?

Comment: routes are pre load , and must fully load , then CI system can start after routes load. i mean can we do routes.php like ajax call that don't effected other part , and make CI independence from routes.php.

Comment: nope it won't work - but i don't understand the purpose of this ;)

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to build your own subclass(MY_Controller).In your controller load the database and write routing directly into routes file with file_put_contents.

Comment: Are you sure?I used this approach for a very big platform that had generated routes...It worked fast because writing to files is very fast,but it also depends how your querries are done.And also you shouldn't have to rewrite your routes on every request,