# Converting a string into URL PHP

Tags: php, url, transliteration

I need to display russian text with eng letters, which I've done, and then I need to convert the resulting sentence into a URL, delete all of the symbols(if needed), inside the result and replace spaces with underscores.

I'm not sure if I need to create different functions or work within this function and if so, how do I put it all together? Please help! Thanks :)

```
function rus_to_lat($str) {
          $rus = array('А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ъ', 'Ы', 'Ь', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я', 'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я');


   $lat = array('A', 'B', 'V', 'G', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'Gh', 'Z', 'I', 'Y', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'F', 'H', 'C', 'Ch', 'Sh', 'Sch', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'E', 'Yu', 'Ya', 'a', 'b', 'v', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'gh', 'z', 'i', 'y', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'f', 'h', 'c', 'ch', 'sh', 'sch', ' ', 'y', ' ', 'e', 'yu', 'ya');

 return str_replace($rus,$lat, $str) ;
}

 echo rus_to_lat('Первый вариант функции возвращает строку с замененной кириллицей') . '<br>';
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine:- https://eval.in/970200  . So what's your problem?

Comment: Pos dupe.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955251/php-function-to-make-slug-url-string

Comment: when the sentence is displayed there are spaces between words, I need them replaced with _

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add space `' ',` in rus array and underscore in lat array `'_',`

```
function rus_to_lat($str) {
 $rus = array(' ', 'А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ъ', 'Ы', 'Ь', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я', 'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я');
 $lat = array('_', 'A', 'B', 'V', 'G', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'Gh', 'Z', 'I', 'Y', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'F', 'H', 'C', 'Ch', 'Sh', 'Sch', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'E', 'Yu', 'Ya', 'a', 'b', 'v', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'gh', 'z', 'i', 'y', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'f', 'h', 'c', 'ch', 'sh', 'sch', ' ', 'y', ' ', 'e', 'yu', 'ya');
 return str_replace($rus,$lat, $str) ;
}

 echo rus_to_lat('Первый вариант функции возвращает строку с замененной кириллицей') . '<br>';
```

or use this function:

```
function rus_to_lat($str)
{
 $rus = array('А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ъ', 'Ы', 'Ь', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я', 'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я');
 $lat = array('A', 'B', 'V', 'G', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'Gh', 'Z', 'I', 'Y', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'F', 'H', 'C', 'Ch', 'Sh', 'Sch', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'E', 'Yu', 'Ya', 'a', 'b', 'v', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'gh', 'z', 'i', 'y', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'f', 'h', 'c', 'ch', 'sh', 'sch', ' ', 'y', ' ', 'e', 'yu', 'ya');
  $str = str_replace($rus, $lat, $str);
  $str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '_', $str);
  return $str;
}

echo rus_to_lat("Первый вариант функции возвращает строку с замененной кириллицей");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple regex to replace all the not desired symbols into "_"

Code example:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '_', $string)
```