# String to SEO-friendly slug

Tags: php, regex

I need to change some of the strings to SEO-friendly slugs. I think I'm pretty close with this:

```
str_replace(array(" ", "&", "(", ")", ".", ",", " - ", "'"), array("-", ""), strtolower($str))
```

However there are couple of cases that I still have issues with. It's when a string has a dash or & as in:

```
I & GN Hospital and Nurses' Quarters
```

produces `i--gn-hospital-and-nurses-quarters` instead of desired
`i-gn-hospital-and-nurses-quarters`

Also I would like to strip anything enclosed in () before creating a slug. For example:

```
Mary Kate Hunter (November 8, 1866 - April 15, 1945)
```

should become `mary-kate-hunter`

I think I'll need another str_replace first to remove it, before creating slug, and possibly use some sort of regex. Or is there a better way?

Comment: This question has been already answered [PHP function to create slug ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955251/php-function-to-make-slug-url-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this code with `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace` to do replacements using a regex.

```
$s = 'I & GN Hospital and Nurses' Quarters';
echo preg_replace("/[\h&(),'-]+/", '-', preg_replace('/\h*\([^)]*\)/', '', $s));
//=> I-GN-Hospital-and-Nurses-Quarters

$p = 'Mary Kate Hunter (November 8, 1866 - April 15, 1945)';
echo preg_replace("/[\h&(),'-]+/", '-', preg_replace('/\h*\([^)]*\)/', '', $p));
//=> Mary-Kate-Hunter
```

Here:

- `preg_replace('/\h*\([^)]*\)/', '', $s)`: Strips out `(...)` text from input
- `preg_replace("/[\h&(),'-]+/", '-', $str)`: Replaces all chosen characters with `-`