# user-friendly URLs reliable with the database

Tags: php, sql, url, user-experience

I have a database containing a table named ***songs*** with a field ***title***.
Now If my url is `http://www.foo.com/songs/xxx` (xxx = the title of the song),
apache is silently redirecting to a page that looks similar to : `/song.php?title=xxx`.

To embellish the URLs I convert spaces into underscores (cause I know some browser display %20 instead of space, not%20really%20user%20friendly%20ya%20know%20what%20i%20mean).

There's a snag cause if the title contains spaces and underscores (e.g. `DJ_underscore fx`) and the script converts it into `DJ_underscore_fx` the sql :

```
    select * from songs where songs.title=xxx
```

can't find it.

> here's the sketch to be more specific:

- a script fetches the different titles in the database
- converts all the space into underscore ( e.g. `name_of the song` ->
  `name_of_the_song` )
- echo them as links ( e.g. `<a
  href="/songs/name_of_the_song">name_of_the_song</a>` )
- the user clicks on the link and requests the document
- apache is silently redirecting ( e.g. `/songs/name_of_the_son` ->
  `/song.php?title=name_of_the_song` )
- *song.php* fetches the specific data ( e.g. `select * from songs where songs.title=name_of_the_song` )

ok you see that there's no entry in the database that looks like `name_of_the_song` but `name_of the song`.

How can I manage the whole so that my URL remains clear and the **title** field is not restricted to a certain amount of values (can have spaces, underscore, dashes, well anything)?

Answer (score 5):

Use something like `/1234/name-of-page/` where `1234` is the primary key ID of the row and `name-of-page` is ignored by your script.

This gives a link directly to the primary key of the entry in the table, which will give you several benefits:

1. No need to have duplicate ID fields.
2. Fast indexing on `SELECT` queries.
3. You still get the readability and SEO benefits of a "pretty" URL.

You might notice that StackOverflow itself does exactly this:

`/questions/8211267/user-friendly-urls-reliable-with-the-database/`

Which probably gets re-written to something like:

`question.php?id=8211267`

Comment: +1. [This is the way to go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647789/problem-in-displaying-a-url-slug-with-dash/2647828#2647828).

Answer (score 3):

Just add another field that will keep the exact name used in URL. And when you have some "duplicates" - just append them with _2, _3 etc or give a way for user to edit and give another name manually.

Comment: Or do something like `/1234/name-of-whatever/` where `1234` is the ID of the object and `name-of-whatever` is ignored by the script.

Comment: @Polynomial: and it is even much better. You should put it as a separate answer

Comment: @zerkms I thought about this solution but as I spent numerous minutes to figure my request out I can't think out of the box right now, I just wished there would had been other solutions, thanks anyway, I just wait for more answers but gotta be the checked answser

Answer (score 1):

What your trying to achieve is definetly the wrong way, you could have hundreds of variations to lookup in your database and is also bad for SEO.

Start by setting a rule that all URL's have _ to seperate the space, that's how most site URL's are done (digg.com being an example).

Then create a seperate field that stores the URL e.g.

```
title     | url
song name | song_name
```

Then do your lookup based on the URL field.

For legacy reasons you could also replace any spaces with _ in your lookup script when you receive the title from the GET before doing the database query.

Answer (score 0):

well, if  you want spaces in the url, people will have it uri encoded for transit. if rather than replacing all _ with spaces, just use a uridecoder (can't remember the exact title). it would still allow for spaces to be typed. On the displayer, the shown text in the link, cant you do an `str_replace` to convert %20 in spaces?

Either that of have a computer friendly version of the title (that doesn't use spaces, but underscores) and a user friendly column that does have the spaces