# Ruby on Rails: Use slug instead of id on resource routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

So I'm looking for a solution that would help me achieve the following with Rails resource:

```
/admin/articles/:slug/edit
```

as opposed to

```
/admin/articles/:id/edit
```

I'm looking for Rails [resource routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) and not the other kinds of routes.

Just wanted to know if it was possible. If so, how?

Comment: I think this is a copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482636/fetching-records-with-slug-instead-of-id

Comment: Consider a gem like friendly_id if you're building a production site, or at least check the readme to get an idea of the edge cases. https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :articles, param: :slug
```

In the terminal:

```
$ rake routes
...
article GET    /articles/:slug(.:format)      articles#show
...
```

Comment: Are you sure that the param option is in Rails 3?

Comment: Should be, but at least it is available in Rails 4+.

Comment: Is this a "one-step" solution? i.e., once you add `param: :slug` your `link_to article.name, article`, for instance, will generate a link to a slug, and that slug will be recognized? Either the answer is no or I'm doing something else wrong :)

Comment: @JonathanTuzman If the path then looks correct (e.g. `/articles/my-great-article`), you'll have to the controller to handle the slug param, e.g. `@article = Article.find_by!(slug: params[:slug])`

Comment: @JonathanTuzman you need to add another method to the model to make sure, the changed parameter gets used with `link_to article`: `def to_param slug end` will make sure, the slug is used instead of the id. More can be read here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters

Answer (score 17):

The `:id` parameter in the routing is simply a placeholder and can be anything, from a numeric identifier to a slug.

You just need to pass the proper value

```
article_path(id: @article.slug)
```

and fetch the article using the appropriate method

```
Article.find_by!(slug: params[:id])
```

If you prefer, you can also override the `to_param` for the `Article` model to return the slug, so that you can use

```
article_path(@article)
```

and automatically the slug will be assigned to the `:id` parameter.