# Rails generate short route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, paperclip, slug, friendly-id

Hi :) I have a question I'm not really sure how to fix or solve the specific problem.

I am using MongoDB .

I would like to make my route small to share it to the public.

For example

> https://example.com/api/v1/users/:user_id/pictures/:picture_id

To

> https://example.com/aghu234

Because I don't want that other users see the how path. I hope you guys can help me :)

Comment: We call that using a "slug"... which will probably help you google for examples by other people... eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059992/ruby-on-rails-resource-routes-use-slug-instead-of-id

Comment: Good luck! if you get stuck on any particular implementation, come back and we'll help you with that :)

Comment: Do you maybe know how to start with that ? I am really new with backend development:/ This is how my route look https://example.com/api/v1/users/:user_id/pictures/:picture_id. I just want to access to the object picture with a friendly id. Like https://example.com/agdh675. I would be really happy if you can help me with a small introduction I am using mongoid as well

Comment: The link to the other stack overflow question has examples of the code you will start with in its answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [shortener](https://github.com/jpmcgrath/shortener) gem, but there is no fun in using 3rd party gems. So, If you want in-house version then you can use following sample code.

```
ALLOWED_CHARACTER_SPACE = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".split(//)
def convert_uid_to_short(uid)
        surl = ''
        base = ALLOWED_CHARACTER_SPACE.length
        while uid > 0
            surl << ALLOWED_CHARACTER_SPACE[uid.modulo(base)]
            uid /= base
        end
        surl.reverse
    end
```

In above method, you have pass `uid`, a unique identifier in integer format for your url/api. It will return a short url for the unique identifier. You can then use the short version in your code appropriately.

**Sample:**

```
convert_uid_to_short(10)
output: k

convert_uid_to_short(1043234)
output: exyw
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.:) What for a awesome community :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [shortener gem](https://github.com/jpmcgrath/shortener), which does exactly what you're asking for.